# vertically centered dot

Tags: symbols

I want to have a function name (like g(.)) and I do this in this ways:

1. `$g \left( . \right)$`
2. `$g(.)$`

But in either way, the dot "." seems a little lower than it is better to be. I am wondering if there is another way to have this output? (this may seem so basic but when I saw that writing three consecutive dots has its own command, I doubted may be I am doing it wrong)

Comment: I changed the title to better match the question. I hope the new title fits with your intention.

Comment: Yeah, definitely it is better. I appreciate it.

Comment: The Wikipedia page for [Interpunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct#Similar_symbols) contains some helpful LaTeX commands.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use `\cdot` for a single vertically centred dot.

Answer (score 35):

In text (non-mathematical) context, the symbol you may be looking for is `\textbullet`. I mention this here because people Google-searching for this answer will likely find this page is result #2, as I did, with no more relevant results above it.

Comment: Thanks. since no context is defined in the question, actually this should be the answer ;)

Comment: \textbullet (in text mode) and \cdot (in math mode) look pretty different; the former is much heavier.  If you want a light dot, one option is just to write $\cdot$, of course. Alternatively, maybe look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419283/middle-dot-interpunct-in-text-mode-with-lualatex).  [Interpunct on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct) maybe also useful for tracking down the symbol you want.

Answer (score 24):

You can use `\mathord{\cdot}` for a centered dot with symbol-like (rather than binary operation-like) spacing.