# Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX

Tags: unicode

How do I enter Unicode characters in LaTeX?  What packages do I need to install and what escape sequence do I type to specify Unicode characters in an ASCII source file?

Comment: is there a reason you can't encode the source file in UTF8?

Comment: @bene, even with that: inputenc with UTF-8 is more of a hack (and a *very* long sequence of translations between byte sequences and correspondig LaTeX commands). It's not pretty.

Comment: Why is everyone recommending XeTeX and not LuaTeX?

Comment: Yeah, LuaTeX FTW!

Comment: If you're a Mac user, you might be interested in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110042/entering-unicode-math-symbols-into-latex-direct-from-keyboard-on-a-mac#110043), which describes how I made a custom keyboard layout full of math symbols, greek letters, and so on.

Comment: @Canageek presumably because Unicode, which is where Lua sucks.

Comment: @flow Wait, what? I thought Lua was good with UTF8 and OFT fonts. My mind is blown.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Have you considered using [XeTeX](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=xetex)? This is an adaptation of TeX that adds Unicode support, and is included in the latest [TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive/) and [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/) distributions. This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX) gives a good introduction.

Comment: Not only Unicode support (that was partially available as an ugly hack-job before) but proper modern font support as well. Very nice, but a pain to get working, at least here :-)

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of using xetex that illustrates what you mean? At minimum, it seems you need to set the default font to something that covers the range of characters you want -- otherwise, characters not covered are simply (and silently!) ignored.

Comment: Unlike the other answers, this doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: You need to add \usepackage{unicode-math}, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394109/85164

Comment: Then use `\char"` followed by the four digit Unicode value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56707992/1458208

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 180):

"Unicode" in this context could mean either in the input or in the output. I assume you're looking to insert something like "©" into your source and have it do something meaningful.

For full support for unicode input and unicode fonts, take a look at XeTeX; it's easy to get started — just select an appropriate font and the unicode characters in your input are directly typeset as unicode glyphs in the output. Switching engines is not always a possibility, however, and sometimes you'll want to stick with pdfTeX for its other useful features.

The best that regular LaTeX (i.e., based from pdfTeX in a modern distribution) can do is recognise UTF-8 sequences in the text and expand macros based on what it sees. Load the `inputenc` package to select the UTF-8 input encoding:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Note that the resulting input file must not have a byte-order mark (BOM) at the beginning, or else it won't compile. (You can also use the `[utf8x]` option which has more extensive coverage but is not as well supported. I don't have any experience using this option.)

To define behaviour for unicode characters, use the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` command that is then defined. Here's an example for binding the control sequence `\dash` to the input character "—"; i.e., a literal em-dash, U+2014, in the source:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{\dash}
```

`\dash` can then be defined in the usual manner; I use:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\dash{%
  \unskip\nobreak\thinspace\textemdash\allowbreak\thinspace\ignorespaces}
```

This defines a dash that has a small space on either side and will only allow a line break *after* it.

Comment: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} worked for me, cheers

Comment: Doesn't work for me. \DeclareUnicodeCharacter has no effect, whether it's in or not, the \dash command works. OTOH, if \DeclareRobustCommand is missing, \dash doesn't work. And where does the Unicode character enter anyways? \DeclareRobustCommand uses \textemdash. 

(Of course this works in a way for the dash, but I tried to transfer it to another Unicode character, U+2318, the "twiddle" known from the Apple command key.)

Comment: I suggest creating a minimal example and asking a new question.

Comment: Note though that in practice there seem to be no constraints against line breaks either before or after an (em-/en-)dash used for parenthetical purposes. See my now updated answer to [this question about hyphens and dashes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/dashes-vs-vs).

Comment: @user14996 I'm fairly sure this is discussed in the TeXbook, and I have no problem consulting Knuth as an authority in this area. Happy to concede that most publications don't do it though — possibly due to the software they use.

Comment: @WillRobertson The only implicit reference I can find is the bottom of p. 95. I'd say Bringhurst is a definite authority on such matters (but I don't know whether he discusses this); Knuth has had an influence on typesetting via TeX, but I don't agree with all of his ideas. I don't find any restrictions on line breaks to the left of dashes in the Chicago Manual of Style. If you can dig up an unambiguous reference, more power to you; *but* plz also include all sources you've checked that turned out to lack such a prescription ;-)

Comment: @user14996 I guess I've been mistaken, then. I wonder where I got this idea? I do prefer it.

Comment: @WillRobertson I don't think such a constraint would be crazy or bad and wouldn't be surprised if *some* publishers obeyed it; the truth is that such finer points of style guides differ. Still, "in the wild" I can't observe such a constraint being there/widespread. Though that definitely doesn't mean that typography in the wild is always best practice. Though on this issue I *personally* don't see a strong reason for a prohibition against breaking before a dash.

Comment: I already had `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` so I tried `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`, but it did not help. I will find some other solution.

Answer (score 71):

This is a minimal example that finally worked for me without using XeTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    The vorticity $ω$ is defined as $ω = ∇ × u$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Roberto, this is a nice trick when you are bound to use no XeTeX. E.g. with `texi2dvi` which I used in R I did not know how to switch the engine. I had to reprogram my rendering functions if it wasn't for your hint here, `mathletters` did the trick, YAY!

Comment: Also works for pdflatex

Comment: [Not great to use `utf8x`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13070/152148). I have an MWE for `xelatex`, but I can't publish it, unfortunately. Let me know if you want me to "*ask the right questions*" that *might* prompt the right answers for you.

Comment: This is a great solution! For those who oppose this solution, I would like to know better what exactly can go wrong with utf8x. Even if I was willing to use "better" compilers, I really need backward compatibility to be 100% sure that my co-authors will be able to compile my files, so yes I'll be using good old pdflatex for a long time

Comment: Remark: Unlike `unicode-math`, `x²³` will create "double superscript error", which causes problem (incorrect typesetting) with `x²³₄₅` for example.

Comment: Does it work for Pdftex on overleaf?

Answer (score 37):

Try `\char"hexcode` like
`\char"2012` for the ‒ (figure-dash). This command works in XeLaTeX and probably other engines

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This will only work in certain TeX engines, especially the unicode-capable ones (XeTeX, LuaTeX). Could you add to your answer in which engine your example worked?

Comment: and how to insert a hexidecimal?

Comment: Thank you.  I have been searching for hours, only to be misdirected to things that don't work.  This is the first solution that works at least for XeLaTeX.  It is kind of shocking, really, that there is NO standard way to simply specify a unicode codepoint in a document and have it work everywhere.

Comment: This does not work for me in XeLaTeX

Comment: Note that •(1) this does not work in PDFlatex, it's explicitly mentioned in the TeXBook that `"AB` only work for at most 2 hexadecimal characters, and •(2) in most case it's possible to simply type out the Unicode character directly (`⌀` instead of `\char"2300` and it will work), •(3) If the character is not available in the font, it will be silently skipped, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45796/unicode-characters-not-displaying-in-xetex

Answer (score 15):

In case anyone is not satisfied with any of the answers: I just had the same problem and came up with my own little solution. I didn't want to dig into another distribution but stay with pdflatex. So I created a textfield in **inkscape**, put the character in, cropped it, and saved as pdf. You can include the pdf in your document like this:

```
\includegraphics[width=1em]{symbol.pdf}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Yes the solution of using an image has been mentioned a few times on this site recently (e.g. at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366019/unicode-with-pdflatex/366180#366180)), but it hasn't been mentioned at this question from 2008 so I've upvoted your answer. Of course, this would be a highly impractical solution in other cases, such as when one has a large number of Unicode characters one wants to enter.

Comment: Problem is that images can't be *text-searched*.

Comment: Odds are, when you trying to include non ASCII characters, people don’t want to search for them. In my case it was the “airplane” character. Of course, I don’t know how popular Tex is in non ASCII-languages.

Comment: Use replace inkscape with Xelatex. Just generate the character you want in Xelatex as a standalone document class and proceed include it as you mentioned above.

Comment: @MoritzH. TeX is _incredibly_ popular in non ASCII-languages (as well), and these languages exceed by far (in their number and in their number of speakers) the "ASCII-only world"

Answer (score 14):

As of 2020, [Arthur Reutenauer says](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb40-2/tb125reutenauer-xetex.pdf) that XeTeX has “gone into maintenance mode,” and the future of TeX development is LuaTeX.  I would therefore recommend using LuaTeX when you can, then XeTeX if you have to, and PDFTeX if it’s all that your publisher supports.

Now that LuaTeX supports complex scripts, the main XeTeX feature I use that LuaTeX does not have (as of July 2020) is interchar tokens.  There are, on the other hand, many LuaTeX features that XeTeX does not have.  I use `microtype` font expansion in nearly every document I create.

If you’re asking what syntax to use to enter Unicode characters, you can use the syntax `^^^^abcd` for U+ABCD, `\char"ABCD`, `\symbol{"ABCD}`, or any of the macros defined by the LaTeX kernel or [`unicode-math`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf).

Answer (score 11):

This answer explains more of the background "what happens internally, and why it seems to be so complex".

|  | PDFTeX | XeTeX/LuaTeX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Text mode | Maintained by LaTeX team (`inputenc`), compose accent on characters | Available by default, if font has character |
| Math mode (legacy font) | Not officially supported | Not officially supported |
| Math mode (OpenType math font) | Not available | Maintained by LaTeX team (`unicode-math`) |

---

### 1   Text mode

#### 1.1   PDFTeX

**Explanation**

> It's commonly said that "PDFTeX does not support Unicode", but
>
> - it doesn't mean you can't type a non-ASCII character like `ǫ` and get that character in the output.
>
> What it means is
>
> - Each UTF-8 character (byte sequence) is interpreted as 2/3 *character tokens*, not 1
> - TeX cannot natively "pick character at position X from *OpenType* font Y and put on the paper". (source
>   [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615187/unicode-in-pdflatex-says-it-only-supports-up-to-255-code-points-when-im-trying#comment1536699_615194)
>   [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366180/250119)
>   [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377729/250119)
>   )
>
>   However, it *can* pick character at position X from old-style (METAFONT) font file Y, and so it's possible
>   to "convert" a OpenType font to old font file*s* (each font file contains maximum 256 characters). See CJK package for an example.
>
> More commonly, characters with accents are composed from a letter and an accent, which is what `inputenc` package does.
>
> Particular example:
>
> - In the case of the letter `ǫ`, internally TeX use `inputenc` library to "convert" the 2 bytes `c7 ab`
>   to the macro `\k o`, which puts the character `o` and the hook on the PDF page.
>
>   If you copy the content on the PDF page, you'll get `o˛` – the character `o` and the hook separately.
>
>   <sub>(it's possible to make the copied content and the displayed content different, see [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429387/why-doesnt-latex-use-unicode-characters-for-subscripts-and-superscripts-in-the#comment1566729_429387), but that's not the point here.)</sub>

**How to fix it?**

As explained above, there's no completely general way.

Either define some way to "draw" the character (`DeclareUnicodeCharacter`), or find some package that draws these characters for you.

In the latter case, use [DeTeXify or Comprehensive LaTeX symbols list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21/250119). <sub>also: [Comprehensive LaTeX symbols, indexed by code point](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/487602/250119)</sub>

**Example questions**

> - [`↔︎ ↕︎`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522945/250119), [`∞`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287795/250119), [`≤`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578705/250119) → use the character from math font.
> - [`⚓`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37445/250119) → `dingbat` package
> - [`Љ Б Д И П و △ ★ ✚ ✠ ✤ ✶ ✸ ❀ ❃`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/347608/250119) → various packages.
> - → `fontawesome5`/`twemojis`
> - [`Ꝃ`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/311057/250119)

##### 1.1.1   PDFTeX versions older than 2018

In these versions, you also need to include

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

so that UTF8 encoding is used. In newer versions, [it's included by default](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370278/250119).

#### 1.2   XeTeX/LuaTeX

In this case, the program *can* typeset the character directly (in XeTeX/LuaTeX, the default encoding is `TU` which allows typesetting character from OpenType font by specifying Unicode character directly) so usually there's no problem.

Special case: if the font does not have the character (for example the character `α` in the default Latin Modern font), it will drop an empty space in. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377729/250119.

Note: [do not ever use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` on XeTeX/LuaTeX!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470976/250119) (unless you know what you're doing)

Side note, by default (TU encoding) LaTeX does some smart thing to automatically convert `` \`y `` to typeset the character `ỳ` in Unicode so copy paste from the PDF works correctly.

**How to fix it?**

Look for a different font.

Example questions

> - [`Днепр kůň dominī Ngữ`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172421/250119) → XITS, libertine
> - [`Π ⦃a : D₀⦄`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235421/250119) → Ubuntu Mono, DejaVu Sans, Segoe UI Symbol
> - [`αβγ`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45796/250119) → Times New Roman (also have solution using `polyglossia`/`newunicodechar`)
> - [`π`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201622/250119) → CMU Serif, DejaVu Sans
> - [`☪`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512298/250119) → Segoe UI Symbol
> - [`ɔ, ɩ, ʋ`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/644247/250119) → Unifont, FreeSerif, DejaVu Serif, EB Garamond

See also

- [Getting xetex to complain when a character is missing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41230/250119) to give an error instead of just a warning.
- [Why are some Unicode characters missing when using XeTeX and Ubuntu Mono?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235421/250119) to determine which fallback font the operating system uses for a particular character (then you can specify that font in TeX, for example).

### 2   Math mode

#### 2.1   PDFTeX

**Explanation**

> The LaTeX team does not define in the `inputenc` package – the most popular one used to process Unicode input -- see [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482111/250119) [2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59997946#59997946) [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377613/solve-unicode-char-is-not-set-up-for-use-with-latex-without-special-handling-o?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment935472_377613).
>
> It's not too clear what's the rationale behind this decision, but one possible reason is, as mentioned in the documentation of `inpmath` package
> (and also in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34843/250119)),
> that there's no known way to implement it in a bulletproof way -- namely if `\ifmmode` check is used without a initial `\relax` then it will fail at the start of `halign` alignment entry,
> but with `\relax` added it will break kerning.
>
> That remark was written back in 2016. Nevertheless, the package itself uses
> `\protected\def\protected@empty{}`, which appears to work without breaking the kerning, so I don't know what's the real rationale...?
> I don't know if there's any other disadvantage.
>
> So, if you use e.g. `∈` in math mode it will not work.
>
> Compare:
>
> | Character | utf8 | utf8x (ucs) | [mathletters]{ucs} |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | `ǫ` | good | good | good |
> | `∈` | not supported | `\ensuremath{\in}` | same |
> | `α` | not supported (requires babel or similar) | `\textalpha` (still requires babel or similar) | `\ensuremath{\alpha}` |
> | `ⁿ` | not supported | `\textsuperscript n` | `\ensuremath{^n}` |
>
> As mentioned in `ucs` package documentation of `mathletters` option:
>
> > This option is disabled by default, because using math greek in a normal text does not look good

**How to fix it?**

Unfortunately, you have to either define them yourself, or resort to third-party packages (none of them are particularly complete at the moment, unfortunately). See part 3 below.

#### 2.2   XeTeX/LuaTeX

**Explanation**

> Without `unicode-math`, the engine uses traditional math font <sup>[source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22455/250119)</sup>, so it has the same problem as above.
>
> With `unicode-math`, the engine uses Latin Modern Math font (by default) <sub>this also explains why there are [some differences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125175/250119) between
> the output with and without `unicode-math` – because the glyph in Latin Modern math font is different</sub>, so you can use characters like `α` in math mode without any problem.
>
> Internally, the package `unicode-math`:
>
> - defines the `mathcode` for each Unicode character (unlike PDFTeX, it's not necessary to make these characters active, because the code point of the character to be typeset is the same as the input character), *and*
> - define the corresponding command (`\alpha`, `\varnothing`, `\mathbb`) to translate to the corresponding Unicode character.

This should work fine, no need to fix.

#### 2.3   Special case

If the character is **not** a Unicode math symbol, but rather a "letter" (and you can already get the letter to show up normally in text mode, see part 1 above), then usually you'd want to use `\text{...}`. [Example question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/647990/250119).

### 3   Use Unicode input with legacy math font

Recall that this is *not supported* by the LaTeX team.

- find some package that defines it

  - [`unicode-math-input` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math-input)

    (disclaimer: I'm the maintainer) I aim to support all the characters that `unicode-math` package supports.
  - [`commonunicode` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/commonunicode) -- works in both engines;
    however this redefines all characters as active, which means it breaks in e.g. `fancyvrb` verbatim environments;
    as well as [using `\ensuremath` everywhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/250119),
    for more details see documentation of `unicode-math-input` package.

    [This](https://gist.github.com/user202729/4a54e705502f10a5cbe16c63f4eb8a20) is the list of characters included in this package but missing in `unicode-math[-input]`.
  - `utf8x` option (`ucs` package). This is highly incompatible with several packages however, see [comparison with `[utf8]inputenc`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13067/250119).
  - `inputenx` package has some math characters, using it depends on some removed `inpmath` package (now source code can be found on the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160427030912/https://latex-project.org/code/experimental/inpmath.zip).
    See also [comparison](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430705/250119).
  - `unixode` package for example, mentioned in other answer.
- defining the characters yourself.

#### 3.1   How to define Unicode characters?

- `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394109/250119) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522946/250119): for `latex` and `pdflatex` only.
- `newunicodechar` package [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125876/250119) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522961/250119): for all engines.

Potentially with some disadvantages e.g. the latter may break usage of these Unicode characters in `fancyvrb` environment, see documentation of `unicode-math-input` for details.

#### 3.2   How to find a table of correspondences?

- [An extensive list of LaTeX symbols and Unicode equivalents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162385/250119)
- from source code of `commonunicode`, `unicode-math-input`, `unicode-math` or `unixode` package.
- from ucs source code. Has approximately 700 (math) symbols. <sub>(based on counting number of lines with `ensuremath` in the generated `.def` files)</sub>
- a list from [flowfram / texparser](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227182/250119) source code.
- from [unicode-math source code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/601583/250119).
  Has approximately 2500 symbols.

  Note that, as explained above, this table is meant to define the command to map to the Unicode character, so

  - there are some Unicode characters that is listed twice.
  - some escape sequences are not defined in the default "legacy math" mode (for example `\muprho` "math upright rho")
- from [unixode source code](https://github.com/olivierverdier/Unixode/blob/master/unixode.sty). Has approximately 100 symbols.
- Miscellaneous unclassified: `texmf-dist/tex/generic/enctex/utf8raw.tex`, `texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfx/l8umath-penc.def`,
  `texmf-dist/tex/luatex/markdown/markdown.lua`, `texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-namedentities.lua`

#### 3.3   Additional information

- Supporting multiple consecutive superscript/subscript characters such as `x²³⁴`:

  - there's a "simple" way of defining `²` to map to `{}^2` for example (approach used by OpTeX in an answer below), but this will **clearly** put the superscript in incorrect positions (because the superscript is relative to the height of the `{}`, not the formula before)
  - there are more complicated ways, refer to [Interpreting unicode ², ³, etc... characters in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/344160/250119).

Comment: .note. Looks like you *can* use computer modern math as OpenType font https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191293/250119 – didn't figure out how.

Answer (score 10):

In order to use XeLaTeX (and even both pdflatex and xelatex on the same document), you can use the simple [`unixode` package](https://github.com/olivierverdier/Unixode):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unixode}

\begin{document}
    The vorticity $ω$ is defined as $ω = ∇ × u$.
\end{document}
```

You may then compile your document either with `pdflatex` or with `xelatex`.

Note: the package is in development; the aim is to support as many unicode equivalents as possible.

Comment: Looking at the code, it only supports Unicode math symbols.

Comment: Also doesn't look like "in development". Last commit in 2016, a pull request from 2016 not merged. (also, not included in TeX live, so need to download source from GitHub.)

Answer (score 7):

As of today, both XeTeX and LuaTeX will let you input unicode without complaining.

Comment: Whether it "complains" depends on HOW you enter it.  You need to be specific on exactly what you mean by "will let you input".

Comment: @ℝaphink Could you show an example on how you would input unicode in LuaLaTeX ?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, I'm not an expert on this, but hope I can at least provide some useful leads.

A lot of the early multi-lingual support for LaTeX predates the widespread adoption of Unicode, although it looks like there's been some consolidation around Unicode recently.  So you might find something useful in specific language support packages, e.g. [CJK LaTeX](https://cjk.ffii.org/) (for Chinese, Japanese and Korean).

Another [Unicode package](https://ctan.org/pkg/ucs) for LaTeX has a new name (formerly `unicode`; now `ucs`).  For a list of Unicode packages, see https://ctan.org/topic/unicode .

You might also have a look at the excellent book [The LaTeX Companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201362996), which includes a section on multilingual text.

Comment: unicode.sty was renamed ucs.sty, and the old name was kept as an alias.  ucs.sty acquired a new maintainer, and it was decided that the alias would be dropped.

Comment: Thanks for answer +1, though `ucs` is incompatible with `biblatex` :_(

Answer (score 2):

This is a minimal example that finally worked for me using OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]

The vorticity $ω$ is defined as $ω = ∇ × u$.
\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for unicode characters defined in a standard font, you can do:
Use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Print some leaves: {\fontspec{Symbola} %the font name
                                      \symbol{"1F343}} %unicode symbol code                  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This finally solved the problem I was struggling for a long time. On Ubuntu I had to first manually download the Symbola font with `sudo apt install fonts-symbola`.

Comment: I'm still struggling to be able to do this on non-standard fonts, particularly in Overleaf.

Comment: Something is wrong with this solution. If you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX then you don't need inputenc at all.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much time to play around and fine tune this answer. If you do and can find a better way, please post an improved answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following tweak helpful when you are dealing with very specific (often weird-looking) unicodes. For instance, if you want to render the Cuneiform Sign Dugud character (U+12082), simply copy-paste the following into a `.tex` file and compile it:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

% The required package
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% The definitioning of the (locally installed) font family
% that supports the unicode symbol
\newfontfamily\NotoSansCuneiform{Noto Sans Cuneiform}

% The definitioning of the literal custom unicode symbol
% The font command and the unicode must be encapsulated within "\text{}",
% otherwise the text will be rendered in Noto Sans Cuneiform
% all the way to the end of the document
\newcommand{\}{\text{\NotoSansCuneiform }}

\begin{document}
The Cuneiform Sign Dugud (U+12082) has the following glyph: \.
\end{document}
```

The following is the screenshot of the entire code (in case your browser cannot render it):

[image: The LaTeX code for rendering U+12082 character]

And the following is the screenshot of the output after rendering using KDE Kile:

[image: The output of rendering U+12082 character using LaTeX]

Look how easy it is to display the U+12082 character!

While [Davislor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554858/301715)'s approach of using `\symbol{"12082}` is definitely working, you can copy-paste the above code into a word processor with some compatible font family. Then the Cuneiform Sign Dugud character (plus a leading "\") will be displayed *literally*, instead of just the number "12082".

However, there are three things to note when using this method:

- You must ensure that the local font family that you are using is compatible with the unicode character that you want to render (e.g., using Unicode Map application in your computer to view a font's supported unicodes).
- Each unicode character must be defined *individually*. And if there are two glyphs that are mapped by two distict font families, both fonts must be defined in the document as well.
- As [ChrisN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34607/301715) has pointed out, the above LaTeX code should be compiled using [XeTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX). This is because the command `\newfontfamily{}` is not supported by PDFLaTeX (the default compiler in several LaTeX editors).

Answer (score 0):

This question is really ambiguous, and I believe the answers are to the wrong interpretation. To have LaTeX *handle* Unicode is what is being answered, what I understand is being asked is how to *enter* such characters into the file. And that depends on the editor used... I've even copy&pasted some from Wikipedia pages into `xemacs` to go around that. The methods given in the [Unicode FAQ](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html) clash with `xemacs` definitions or get interpreted at random by `gnome-terminal` :-(

Answer (score 0):

Just linking to this other answer that uses `unicode-math`’s source file to automatically define all symbols: [Unicode maths in pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601579/unicode-maths-in-pdflatex)

Comment: Actually I already include this link in my answer.