# Can't compile Japanese quotation marks made using Vim digraphs

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, japanese

Rather than using floor and ceiling, I'd rather use what I would consider a proper `UTF-8` character for Japanese quotation marks. Not only is it more intuitive, but it looks better (or should). I can do this using `ctrl+K <'` and `ctrl+K >'` in Vim, my text editor of choice since.

However, when I try to compile this, it throws errors at me. In particular:

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character 」 (U+300C) (inputenc)
>   not set up for use with LaTeX.
>
> See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.

So I press `H` for immediate help, and it mentions that I need to `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` so put in

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{300C}{「}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{300D}{」}
```

But it still fails with the same error.

I also tried `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{300D}{\「}` and `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{300C}{\」}`

I also tried `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{300D}{\jpr}` but was given an "undefined control sequence error". However, even if this did work, it isn't what I want. I was doing this as a troubleshooting step.

This is especially frustrating since looking on line at sample docs, people just use the brackets without any special treatment, yet I'm using the `CJK` package.

I've also tried `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` which I previously chose not to use because it lead to undesirable behavior. Again, a troubleshooting step.

It was suggested I produce a minimum "working" example. Below is that example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJK}
\begin{document}
「
\end{document}
```

Another piece of info not requested is the compiler. Its `pdflatex` without any options.

Comment: You'll get a better answer (and probably sooner) if you post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497).

Comment: @Teepeemm done, though I'm not sure that really adds anything.

Comment: I do think the MWE will help (although I have to admit that I'm not versed in unicode and encodings).  Regarding the compiler: must it be `pdflatex`?  I believe `lualatex` and `xelatex` are especially suited to dealing with unicode.

Comment: I've been working on this set of macros and preamble for 10 years. My documents don't compile in either xetex or lualatex and fixing them is likely more effort than fixing this problem. Not only that, but I have hundreds (probably over 1k) pages written with the current combination which suddenly wouldn't compile. I have everything in a Git repo, but still. . .

Comment: It's meaningless to write `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{300C}{「}` or `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{300C}{\「}` — the whole point is to define what should be done with that Unicode character, in terms of things already known to the engine (i.e. give it a definition that does not involve that Unicode character). (Assuming not XeTeX/LuaTeX….) Also, if you want to type Unicode characters in the file, you need inputenc. (Explained many times on this site, e.g. [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373812/48), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377729/48), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366180/48).)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to enclose CJK characters in `\begin{CJK}` ... `\end{CJK}` when using CJK package. For example, if you are using pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{ipxm}
「さくら」
\end{CJK}

\end{document}
```