# Include Chinese characters into article in Xelatex

Tags: xetex, cjk

when I try to incorporate some Chinese characters into an article complied by Xelatex, something goes wrong. The Chinese characters don't show up.
My code is as below,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bkai}
        \begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    {  經濟系  \\
Department 
    \centering
    \thispagestyle{empty}       
\end{titlepage}
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `Missing character: There is no 經 in font [lmroman17-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!`. (It's a bug / design flaw in (Xe)TeX that this is only logged to the log file, and cannot be made an error: see [Getting xetex to complain when a character is missing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41230/getting-xetex-to-complain-when-a-character-is-missing).) You need to specify a font for those characters. (Also btw you have a missing `}`)

Comment: But how can I specify a font?

Comment: Basically the `CJKutf8` package is not meant for XeLaTeX. Either you can remove `\fontspec` and compile with `pdflatex`, or remove the `CJKutf8` package and maybe use `xeCJK`. I can post an answer that seems to work for me, but as I can't read Chinese I'm not sure if it's right :-) Have you seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex)?

Answer (score 5):

The main problem in the above is that the `CJKutf8` package (and `babel`) are meant for `pdflatex`, not `xelatex`. Here is an absolutely minimal way of using (occasional) Chinese characters in XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\cjkfont{Noto Sans CJK SC} % Or any appropriate font you have
\begin{document}
{\cjkfont 經濟系} Department
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Result]

But if you're going to be writing a lot of Chinese you probably want to do a lot more, for which you can use the more sophisticated approaches described at the question [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex)

Comment: Thanks for your help.
But it return an error,
Undefined control sequence. \newfontfamily\cjkfont

Comment: @ChYh Are you sure you compiled the same file as above, and with `xelatex`? The command `\newfontfamily` is defined by the package `fontspec`, so after `\usepackage{fontspec}` you shouldn't have any problem using it.

Comment: @ChYh Did it work? (If the above file doesn't compile you can edit the full output into the question.)

Answer (score 0):

In default the Chinese font is not set. You can simply use `\documentclass{ctexart}`, which help you set up fonts and many other stuff.

Comment: Please, can you add a minimal working example of the your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the xeCJK package, though it requires the XeLaTeX engine. As in the answer from @ShreevatsaR, if the character is rarer, you may need to change the font.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK TC}

\begin{document}
This tests the traditional Chinese character 錄. 

It has Unicode ID 37636. 
\end{document}
```

On Overleaf, at time of writing, this example will only work with the font change line, as the default Chinese font is Fandol, which doesn't have 錄. Note the directive `\setCJKmainfont` instead of `\setmainfont`.