# How to insert Chinese characters into the following template? (I'm already in XeLatex mode) And it has to be compatible with the English characters

Tags: xetex, chinese

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Random Stuff %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{-3.0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{-1pt}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.6in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.19in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.7in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.4in}
\urlstyle{same}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-7pt}\scshape\raggedright\large\bfseries
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{0pt}]
% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
\pdfgentounicode=1

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Commands  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
  \item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-3pt}}
  }
}
\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-3pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & \textbf{\small #2} \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}
\newcommand{\resumeSubheadingContinue}[2]{
  \vspace{-3pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}
\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
  \vspace{-3pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & \textbf{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}
\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{0pt}}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}
\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.0in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{0pt}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        % NAME
        {\Huge\scshape 张三} 
        % SUBHEADING
        \\
        \vspace{0.15cm}
        {\raisebox{-0.2\height}{\faPhone}
        {}}
        \vline ~
        % EMAIL
        \href{}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}{\faEnvelope}  \underline{}}
        \vline ~
        % LINKEDIN
        \href{}
        {\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faLinkedin\ \underline{LinkedIn}}
        \vline ~
        % GITHUB
        \href{}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faGithub\ \underline{GitHub}}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably easiest is to just use [xeCJK](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/686808/119). Don't forget to set a CJK main font.

Comment: Your code works by commenting the two lines `\input{glyphtounicode}` and `\pdfgentounicode=1` which are don't needed for Xelatex engine.

Comment: I shouldn't say this two commands are not needed. They are used to solve the issue when you copy and paste your pdf outputs to another location and you didn't get the correct contents. And they are only working in pdflatex enigne. If you don't have this issue, you can safely delete them.

Comment: @Tom, that works now! Thank you so much for providing the help! Here's another quick issue - the Chinese characters look too large right now, and they don't look as good as the original English style. I'm wondering how to make both the Chinese and English texts have the same font and style. Thanks in advance!