# ! Undefined control sequence. for Hindi Unicode chars

Tags: texlive, unicode, indic, hindi

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{displaymath}
स्कूल
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

This tex file throwing error **! Undefined control sequence.**

I want to to use Unicode hindi chars in tex

Comment: Have you considered using XeTeX instead?

Comment: yes I compile same file with xetex and it gives same error.
and with xelatex it does not give any error but pdf came blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening in your case is that `utf8x` defines (for instance) the letter `स` as `\textdevanagarisa`. I think that in turn is meant to be used with the `LDV` font encoding, which tries to use `arialuni090t`, and… it's all a mess.

Instead, just use XeTeX, with any font of your choice — compile the following with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS} % Or any font of your choice, which covers Devanagari
\tracinglostchars=2 % Usability bug in TeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41230/48

\begin{document}
स्कूल
\end{document}
```

You can use any system font that covers the Devanagari characters that you care about. (Also, you may want to pass `[Script=Devanagari]` to `\setmainfont`.) If your document contains a mixture of Devanagari and non-Devanagari (English, say) text, then you can use the `polyglossia` package and switch between languages when necessary, etc.