# Displaying a character in math mode from its Unicode encoding

Tags: xetex, symbols, luatex, unicode, unicode-math

> Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or simply tell me how I can use the [coptic letter "Me"](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2C98) in math mode?

---

I want to use a [coptic letter](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2C98) in a mathematical expression in my TeX document. From my very limited understanding of how all these things work I read that *"XeTeX and LuaTeX support Unicode"*.
Not entirely sure what that actually means I came across the (XeTeX and LuaTex) commands `\char"xxxx`, `\symbol{xxxx}` and `^^^^xxxx` only to find out that I have no idea how to actually use them. I tried out this little code example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
Trying to display the symbols ©, ❤ and the coptic letter "Me": \\
\char"00a9, \char"2764, \char"2C98  \\
\par
And now again in math mode: \\
$\char"00a9, \char"2764, \char"2C98 $
\end{document}
```

Which yielded the following output:
[image: output1]

---

Similarly, with the second command I get:

```
Trying to display the symbols ©, ❤ and the coptic letter "Me": \\
\symbol{00a9}, \symbol{2764}, \symbol{2C98} \\
\par
And now again in math mode: \\
$\symbol{00a9}, \symbol{2764}, \symbol{2C98}$
```

[image: output2]

and for the last one I even get an error message:

```
Trying to display the symbols ©, ❤ and the coptic letter "Me": \\
^^^^00a9, ^^^^2764, ^^^^2C98 \\
\par
And now again in math mode: \\
$^^^^00a9, ^^^^2764, ^^^^2C98$
```

yields

```
! ^^^^ needs four hex digits. ^^^^ 00a9, ^^^^2764, ^
```

Comment: you are using the default latin modern fonts which do not have that character (there will be missing glyph warnings in the log)

Comment: hex digits must be lowercase for the `^^` notation (and must be uppercase if used as a number with `"`) so `^^^^00a9` is an error.

Comment: See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41230/48) and add `\tracinglostchars=2` to all your `.tex` files. IMO it's a bug in TeX, inherited by XeTeX, that missing characters not only allow the program to complete successfully, but also have the warning hidden in the log file by default.

Comment: See also [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex). (case 1.2 in my answer, by the way.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a font that has the character. On my machine Firefox used Segoe UI Symbol to display this, so I used the same in lualatex:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newfontfamily\zzzz{Segoe UI Symbol}

\begin{document}
Trying to display the symbols ©, ❤ and the coptic letter "Me" {\zzzz(Ⲙ)}: 


And now again in math mode: \\
$ \text{\zzzz Ⲙ}  $

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that `\char"00a9` will try to print the character in slot 0 and then “a9”, because TeX hexadecimal numeric notation requires uppercase letters. To the contrary, the `^^^^` notation requires lowercase letters.

So either `\char"00A9` or `^^^^00a9`. They can't be mixed. There's a big difference among the two: the former is an instruction to print the glyph in position `"00A9` of the current font, the latter *is* the character `U+00A9`.

Now, if the current font, be it in text mode or math mode (what's the current font in math mode depends on many factors) doesn't contain a glyph at a certain position, no fallback is used in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and so you end up with no glyph (or a placeholder).

In order to obtain a glyph in a different font, you have to declare what font to use.

At this point, if you want to use the Coptic letter Me in math, you can even declare it as a math symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% use a font which has the glyph
\newfontfamily{\copticfont}{FreeSerif}[
  NFSSFamily=coptic,
]

\DeclareSymbolFont{coptic}{TU}{coptic}{m}{n}
% need to use a low level declaration
\Umathchardef\Me="0 \symcoptic "2C98

\begin{document}

$\Me+\Me$

\end{document}
```

You can even be bold and use the symbol itself in math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% use a font which has the glyph
\newfontfamily{\copticfont}{FreeSerif}[
  NFSSFamily=coptic,
]

\DeclareSymbolFont{coptic}{TU}{coptic}{m}{n}
% need to use a low level declaration
\Umathchardef\Me="0 \symcoptic "2C98
\Umathcode`Ⲙ="0 \symcoptic "2C98

\begin{document}

$\Me+\Me$

$Ⲙ+Ⲙ$

\end{document}
```

[image]