LuaTeX dvi output missing non-Unicode ligature
If I process the following LaTeX document, "bug.tex" ...
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lato Light}
\begin{document}
Setting
\end{document}

... to dvi with ...
lualatex --output-format=dvi bug.tex 

... the dvi output only contains glyphs for "S", "e", "n", and "g".  The "tti" ligature is missing.
Output from dviasm shows only four glyphs being set (dviasm appears to show glyphs as ASCII interpretations of glyph ids, so, e.g., glyph 34 is capital "S" in the Lato Light file so becomes ASCII double-quote '"', glyph 59 is "e" so becomes ASCII semi-colon ';', etc) ...
[preamble]
id: 2
numerator: 25400000
denominator: 473628672
magnification: 1000
comment: ' LuaTeX output 2024.12.18:0817'

[postamble]
maxv: 0pt
maxh: 272.729996pt
maxs: 5
pages: 1

[font definitions]
fntdef: [/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/typoland/lato/Lato-Light.ttf] at 10pt

[page 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
push:
  right: -72.270004pt
  down: -72.270004pt
  xxx: 'header=l3backend-dvips.pro'
pop:
push:
  push:
    push:
      push:
        push:
          right: -72.270004pt
          down: -65.074997pt
          fnt: [/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/typoland/lato/Lato-Light.ttf] at 10pt
          set: '"'
          right: -0.050003pt
          set: ';'
          right: -0.014999pt
          set: 'm]'
        pop:
      pop:
    pop:
  pop:
pop:

Is this a known issue?  Is there something that I am doing wrong?
With earlier versions of LuaTeX/luaotfload-tool, when glyphs were encoded within dvi using UTF-8, I have seen special-casing happening for ligatures like "tti" that have no Unicode code point, but at least those glyphs existed within the dvi - lack of existence presents a much greater challenge for me :)
Note that the "tti" ligature is present when processing to pdf, i.e., ...
lualatex bug.tex

... produces the image below ...

I am on Ubuntu 24.04 ...
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

... and my luatex version is ...
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023/Debian)
Development id: 7581

$ luaotfload-tool --version
luaotfload-tool version: "3.26"
Revision: nil
Lua interpreter: stock; version "Lua 5.3"
Luatex version: 1.17


As suggested by @ShreevatsaR (thanks!) ...
Log file from unsuccessful run to generate dvi output with \tracinglostchars=3 ...
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023/Debian)  (format=lualatex 2024.1
1.19)  20 DEC 2024 13:52
 restricted system commands enabled.
**bug-tracing.tex
(./bug-tracing.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-22>
Lua module: luaotfload 2023-08-31 3.26 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/pmur002/.texlive2023/texmf-va
r/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-08-19.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2023-
08-19.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.133
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/pmur002/.texlive2023/texmf-va
r/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (/usr/share/texlive/tex
mf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2022/10/10 v1.3b Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2023/07/08 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 77.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks17
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count185
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count186
\c@sapage=\count187

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2022/10/10 v1.3b Default configuration file for 'standalon
e' class
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/pmur002/.texlive2023/tex
mf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz
Inserting `luaotfload.dvi' in `pre_shipout_filter'.)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85/luatex85.sty
Package: luatex85 2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode is ignored in DVI mode.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks19
)
\sa@box=\box51
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-01-22 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2024-01-04 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count196
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box53
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box54
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count197
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count198
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count199
))
Package: xparse 2023-10-10 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2022/01/15 2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
Package: fontspec-luatex 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count270
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count271
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count272
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count273
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count274
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count275
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count276
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen140
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen141
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen142

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache loaded from /home/pmur002/.texlive2023/texmf-v
ar/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc.

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "LatoLight/BI" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "LatoLight/B" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "LatoLight/I" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).

luaotfload | aux : font no 25 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script latn
 with language dflt

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'LatoLight(0)' created for font 'Lato
(fontspec)             Light' with options [Ligatures=TeX].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"LatoLight:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;
"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 


(./bug-tracing.aux)
\openout1 = bug-tracing.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 5
.
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/LatoLight(0)/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/LatoLight(0)/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/LatoLight(0)/m/n --> TU/LatoLight(0)/m/n on input li
ne 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/LatoLight(0)/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/LatoLight(0)/b/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/LatoLight(0)/m/n --> TU/LatoLight(0)/b/n on input li
ne 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/LatoLight(0)/b/it on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 5.

[1


Missing character: There is no ম (U+09AE) in font nullfont!
.
<argument> ...not:N \tex_shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box 
                                                  \__shipout_drop_firstpage_...
l.7 \end{document}
                
? 
] (./bug-tracing.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-22>
 ***********
)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 3651 strings out of 476553
 100000,1977958 words of node,token memory allocated
 563 words of node memory still in use:
   5 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 1 disc, 4 glue, 6 kern, 14 glyph, 6 attribute, 48 g
lue_spec, 6 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:24,3:8,4:1,5:25,6:3,7:76,9:33,11:3
 25630 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 28 fonts using 5966903 bytes
 79i,5n,89p,269b,212s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
Output written on bug-tracing.dvi (1 page, 380 bytes).

NOTE that a run generating pdf is successful and produces a pdf with the correct font (and the "tti" ligature) ...
pdffonts bug-tracing.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
BTUDGJ+Lato-Light                    CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0


May I ask why you need dvi instead of pdf?

Sure.  I am rendering from the dvi (https://github.com/pmur002/xdvir)

Do you have "\tracinglostchars=3" (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41230/getting-xetex-to-complain-when-a-character-is-missing) and have you looked at https://texfaq.org/FAQ-misschar ? And can you share the full log of the compilation?

I have edited the original to include the log from the (unsuccessful) run.

@PaulMurrell Ah I posted an answer, but only towards the end of writing it I realized that you had an unsuccessful run — I think you may just need to update your TeX Live version.

I cannot reproduce the compilation failure, but I can reproduce the dviasm output. But that has a simple explanation. The DVI format specifies a bunch of different op codes for set commands:

In this case, with your \setmainfont{Lato Light} font, which contains a "tti" ligature glyph, LuaTeX (LuaHBTeX) uses a set2 instruction. This is the debug output I get from my custom DVI parser (modified one I had written for another answer):
238: set '34'
242: set '59'
246: setN '129': 9 (0x09), 174 (0xAE)
249: set '109'
250: set '93'

so you can see that in byte offset 246 of the DVI file, there is a set2 instruction with two bytes 0x09 0xAE, which if I'm doing it correctly means glyph 2478, which (using ttx from fonttools) does seem to be the "tti" ligature:
        <LigatureSet glyph="t">
          <Ligature components="t,f" glyph="glyph00131"/>
          <Ligature components="t,i" glyph="glyph02478"/>
          <Ligature components="t,iogonek" glyph="glyph00132"/>

If you don't get the same opcodes in your DVI file, there may be an even simpler explanation, that you're using an older LuaTeX version which had some bugs now fixed: my output starts with:

This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)  (format=lualatex 2024.6.3)

and doesn't have the warnings you show in the question, about

Missing character: There is no ম (U+09AE) in font nullfont!

