# How can I get a servicemark in latex?

Tags: symbols, unicode

I looked at Will Robertsons answer to
[Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex)
which explains how to enter a unicode character but it uses `\textemdash` and I don't know if a LaTeX command exists.

The unicode number is 2120 and it looks like:

## Some service℠

Comment: Why not just use `Some service$^{\textrm{\scriptsize SM}}$` that you can make into command like, say, `\smark` and use `Some service\smark`?

Comment: `\textsuperscript{\scshape sm}`?

Comment: Werner: it has to be one char like the TM symbol. 
Egreg: the level of the text isn't right. It should be the same as the TM symbol but with an S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `\textservicemark`, a macro provided by the `textcomp` package? Its output looks like this:

[image]

**Addendum** In your comment, you mention you'd like to use Minion Pro as the font. Assuming that you can run either `xelatex` or `lualatex` on your system, the following MWE shows how you might get a Service Mark symbol (set here in "Myriad Pro", a sans-serif font which often accompanies "Minion Pro"):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
\renewcommand\textservicemark{\ensuremath{{}^\textsf{\scriptsize SM}}}
\begin{document}
Some service\textservicemark
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thats the one! Just found out that Minion Pro doesn't have the glyph though.

Comment: Please see the addendum for an example of how you might be able to create your own "Service Mark" symbol in Minion/Myriad Pro.

Comment: Settled on \renewcommand\textservicemark{\unskip\nobreak\textsuperscript{\scshape{\scriptsize SM}}\allowbreak\thinspace\ignorespaces}

Comment: Two comments: (i) It should be "sm" and not "SM", right? (`\scshape` has no effect on uppercase letters.) (ii) Do you need the `\thinspace`?

Comment: If I end up changing it to something else other than smallcaps it will need to be uppercase and it matches the output better.

The thin space is needed as otherwise it seems too close to the next character (using minion pro).