# Unicode characters not displaying in XeTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode

I am trying to  get Unicode characters to compile into a PDF file using XeLaTeX. My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Here is α, β, and finally γ.

\end{document}
```

When I compile to PDF I get

```
Here is , , and finally .
```

My Unicode characters do not show up. Could anyone point out my problem?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377729/250119 for more information on the "missing character in font" problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default font, Computer Modern Roman, just does not have the glyphs for these Unicode characters. There are several possibilities to point out:

### Math symbols

If the intended use of the characters is as shortcuts for `\alpha`, `\beta`, etc., then use the [`newunicodechar`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar) package:

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{α}{\alpha}
...
```

### Internationalised typesetting

If you're looking to typeset a document (or part of a document) in the Greek language, use the [`polyglossia`](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) package:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setotherlanguage{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman} % Has Greek characters

...

\begin{greek} ελληνικά \end{greek}
```

### Random usage

If you need these characters for occasional use in the normal text, you can also use the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package without `polyglossia` to load a font that has the glyphs. You can do it either globally (change the font altogether) or just for these characters:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\timesfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

...

The Greek letter alpha follows: {\timesfont α}
```

Comment: Concerning `newunicodechar`, is there a package that collects a large list of existing shortcuts, especially for mathematics and the occasional foreign symbol?

Comment: @GregGraviton: I had the same question. I made a package for that available on github: https://github.com/olivierverdier/Unixode