# Why are missing characters reported as warnings and not errors?

Tags: fonts, errors, symbols, warnings

In the following example, the PDF compiles without error using `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
Hello there. Do you know  ?
\end{document}
```

The  character, however, is missing in the PDF.

The log file shows:

```
Missing character: There is no  in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text!
```

Why is this a warning and not an error?

Comment: I suppose because this is not a syntax error.

Comment: it has nothing to do with TeX

Comment: Because the code works. The problem lies with the tool that the code is using (the font), so it's not critical. The code compiles anyway.

Comment: Errors could be problematic. Missing characters can pop up in curious places see e.g. https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/101/

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41230/getting-xetex-to-complain-when-a-character-is-missing and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201622/why-does-xetex-not-display-basic-unicode-characters