# Different rendering of µ (micro) and other unicode symbols when compiling with XeTeX

Tags: xetex, listings, input-encodings, font-encodings

This is not a "how-to" question but rathe a "why" question.

I'm working on re-writing a MS Word document in LaTeX to be compiled with **XeTex**. I noticed some symbols not showing, especially a µ (or "micro") symbol, sometimes showing and sometimes not. Following mcve shows the behaviour (Note: Compiling with Pdflatex will throw an `! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.` error on several lines.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrarticle}

\begin{document}
\ \\
GREEK SMALL LETTER MU: μ\\
MICRO SIGN: µ\\
German Umlaut: äöü ÄÖÜ ß\\
Some greek letters: αΑ βΒ \\
mathematical symbols: ,  \\ 
\end{document}
```

The Output looks like this:

[image]

Clearly the first instance of `µ` is missing. After some digging, I found that those two symbols translate to different Ansi in Notepad++, the first being `Î¼`, the second being `Âµ`.

Why does the first µ fail to render but not the second? Why do greek capital letters render but not small ones?
I'm pretty sure it has to do with encodings but I fail to understand exactly what's going on.

**Edit:** The answer of Chris H below seems to confirm different unicode characters being the culprit, so I updated the example with more unicode characters that reproduce the behaviour. The reason why some unicode characters render and others don't is still not clear to me.

Comment: By chance I was looking in something completely different but also involving the Micro Sign / Greek mu. The Micro Sign is in unicode terms u+00b5 whilst the greek mu is u+03bc (see e.g. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b5/index.htm and https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03bc/index.htm) In your comments these 2 look identical but (verified by an octal dump and shown by you in notepad++ as well) are different, so probably here lies your problem.

Comment: Obviously that IS the source of my problem. I'm just wondering why some unicode symbols render and others don't. Is that due to a missing representation of that unicode symbol in the default font? I edited my code example to show some more unicode symbols that don't render and others that do.

Comment: Actually it not only happens in the `lstlistings` package, but also in regular text - without any warning. Editing my example to be "real minimal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit of more investigation, I could reproduce the behaviour outside of `lstlisting` as well. This brought me to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201622/why-does-xetex-not-display-basic-unicode-characters).
The answer is, that the font I'm using is missing these unicode characters, which is also shown in the extended log - but not shown as a warning when compiling, such as:

```
Missing character: There is no μ in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
```

Answer (score 4):

A couple of tools combine to figure out what's going on.  First [string-functions.com](http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx), converts your Ansi strings to the seemingly identical μ and µ respectively (set the input encoding to ISO8859-1 and the output to UTF-8).  Copy-pasting from your quoted source also works, but I wanted to start from the known-different characters.  Pasting those two *mu*s into a Python3 script gives:

```
>>> print (hex(ord("μ")))
0x3bc
>>> print (hex(ord("µ")))
0xb5
```

Confirming, as in Albert's comment, that the first is GREEK SMALL LETTER MU and the second is MICRO SIGN (in caps according to the Unicode standards).

So `listings` is rendering micro signs successfully, but not Greek letters.  Unicode allows fonts to use the same glyph for multiple codepoints, so they can indeed be pixel-identical.

---

Here's a Python script to check for Unicode characters in the whole source (pasted into the multi-line string `source`, note the `r'''` to start a raw multiline string and `'''` to end a multiline string.

```python
import unicodedata
source=r'''\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrarticle}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    frame=trBL, 
    language=C++, 
    basicstyle=\small, % make fontsize a little smaller to better fit code
    showstringspaces=false, % don't mark spaces in strings
    %numbers=left, % display line numbers on the left
    commentstyle=\color{teal}, % comment color
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}, % keyword color
    stringstyle=\color{red} % string color
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
public Byte SomeCurrent;  //Current measured in μA
public Byte OtherCurrent; //Other current in µA
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}'''

header=["char","codepoint","position", "name"]
print (header)
for i,char in enumerate(source):
    if ord(char)>127:
        line=[char, hex(ord(char)), i, unicodedata.name(char)]
        print (line)
```

The output it gives is:

```
['char', 'codepoint', 'position', 'name']
['μ', '0x3bc', 542, 'GREEK SMALL LETTER MU']
['µ', '0xb5', 590, 'MICRO SIGN']
```

It would be easy to read in the source from a file, and to give the line number and position within the line of each unicode character, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This isn't surprising when the default way of entering non-keyboard characters in Word (and indeed on Windows in general) is visual. To an earlier writer it looked right.  I'm on Linux and type some Unicode characters (like µ, °, and ×) from memory; for Greek I use a cheat sheet, but either way it's keyboard->codepoint

Comment: I'm still puzzled, why the micro sign renders correctly and the greek small letter doesn't. I naively thought, Xetex would get right of that kind of encoding mess automagically... Fortunately, the µ I have on my keyboard is the one that renders ;)

Comment: @Dschoni having micro-mu is a big advantage of German keyboard layouts.  I don't think Xetex and listings have much choice, as the glyph might be separate, but I suspect the issue is mainly listings.  It's commonly used with pdflatex and didn't originally have (much) support for unicode

Comment: I tested in regular text and it is not limited to `lstlistings`. Updated my question.