# Why are some Unicode characters missing when using XeTeX and Ubuntu Mono?

Tags: xetex, unicode, minted

I'm trying to typeset a document using minted code listings that contain quite some amount of non-standard Unicode characters. I'd like to use Ubuntu Mono as a monospaced font. The following supresses unicode characters:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{java}
Π ⦃a : D₀⦄
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Am i doing something wrong or is the font just not as complete as I'd like it to be?

Comment: Hi and welcome, you can use tools like *fontforge* to view the different letters of a font. If the respective code point is empty or crossed out, the font does not contain the glyph.

Comment: The end of the log-file reveals some bad news `Missing character: There is no ⦃ in font Ubuntu Mono/OT:script=latn;language=DF LT;!`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you know how to set a substitution font and what font would you use for that?

Comment: To be quite honest, no idea what font may contain that glyph, especially in a monospace/ttype version. It seems a bot odd to me, that you have a mathematical formula in a code listing, or monospaced in general. Out of interest, is there a special reason?

Comment: It's code for the theorem prover [Lean](http://leanprover.github.io/). Is there a way to find out what substitution font my editors on Ubuntu use for this glyph? Because there, it looks pretty nice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the missing characters from a font that has them:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}
\newfontfamily{\freeserif}{FreeSerif}

\newunicodechar{⦃}{\makebox[.5em]{\freeserif⦃}}
\newunicodechar{⦄}{\makebox[.5em]{\freeserif⦄}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{java}
Π ⦃a : D₀⦄
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The red boxes are a `pygmentize` problem.

The characters are also in DejaVu Sans; here's how they appear (with also a workaround for the red boxes):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{%
  \let\MINTEDPYGdefault\PYGdefault
  \renewcommand\PYGdefault[2]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{err}%
      {\MINTEDPYGdefault{n}{#2}}%
      {\MINTEDPYGdefault{#1}{#2}}%
  }%
}

\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}
\newfontfamily{\freeserif}{DejaVu Sans}

\newunicodechar{⦃}{\makebox[.5em]{\freeserif⦃}}
\newunicodechar{⦄}{\makebox[.5em]{\freeserif⦄}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{java}
Π ⦃a : D₀⦄
XXXXXXXXXX
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I'll look for a non-serif replacement font though.

Comment: @javra They are also in DejaVu Sans

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see what font your browser is using.

If I "inspect element" on your code above (as viewed in FF/Windows) it says Segoe UI Symbol

so

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Segoe UI Symbol}

\begin{document}

\texttt{Π ⦃a : D₀⦄}

\begin{minted}{java}
Π ⦃a : D₀⦄
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Showing the font works fine, the red boxes are because minted (or rather pygmentize)
not unreasonably thinks the syntax is a Java error, but that's a style choice in the
language settings not an error in the typesetting.

Comment: for what it's worth, on my Mac OS seems Firefox renders the funny braces with `Apple Symbols`.

Comment: as noted by the red boxes, this isn't actually monospace though...

Comment: indeed, same here on Mac OS with `Apple Symbols`.