# Which symbol to put between paragraphs?

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for a nice symbol to mark the separation between two paragraphs.

This is a for a short document, with 3-4 paragraphs.

Comment: Well, this is very opinon based. Some would use a short line, some will use `\skull` ;-)

Comment: Yes, indeed, very opinion based. I wanted to have good ideas from the community.

Comment: Perhaps a visit to the site's chat would be better? The Stackexchange model is really not about soliciting opinion, but factual answers (within reasonable interpretations). But the question's also not really about TeX-LaTeX either. If you'd chosen a symbol and wanted to know how to get it (assuming the answer wasn't a trivial duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character) that might be different, but this has perfectly little to do with LaTeX itself. Perhaps graphicdesign might be a better home, but it'd still be POB

Comment: Asterisms and fleurons.  Perhaps this is the question you seek: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160336/asterism-and-similar-breaking-non-breaking-options

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, kind of, but a better answer has been given here :)

Comment: I am pleased that you received extra value in your current round of answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very 'baroque' style `psvectorian` symbols (No, I don't use them personally!)

Compile with `--shell-escape` enabled or compile with `latex` 'only', since it uses `PostScript` based graph drawing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{psvectorian}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\hfil\psvectorian[scale=0.2]{60}\hfil

\blindtext

\hfil\psvectorian[scale=0.2]{60}\hfil

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow ! great ! I'm looking for something like that but a little less baroque ;-) Well done!

Comment: @Colas: There are many other `symbols` in that package. Take a look ;-)

Comment: Yep and it is in French ;-)

Comment: So far, `49` is my choice :-)

Comment: Thanks for this; what awesome ornaments - wish I knew of this earlier

Answer (score 4):

Common esp. in old books is the hedera ❦ (u+x2766) or turned hedera ❧ (u+x2767), newer books often use an asterisk * or triple asterisk (asterism) ⁂ (u+x2012).

Edit as hinted by comment: How to correctly enter depends on the compiler you use. Cf. [How to easily use UTF-8 with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172421/how-to-easily-use-utf-8-with-latex) and related questions.

Comment: Might be worth adding the (La)TeX code for those symbols (other than the asterisk, which is trivial). e.g. `\ding{166}`, `\ding{166}` (pifont)