# unicode with plain xetex

Tags: xetex, unicode, plain-tex

Related to this [xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45796/unicode-characters-not-displaying-in-xetex#45800) question.
I get `Missing character: There is no π in font cmr10!`.  So I set the unicode font to cmu (computer modern unicode) as advised by [this question for xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201622/why-does-xetex-not-display-basic-unicode-characters/201627#201627)

```
\font\cmu=cmu10 at 10pt
\cmu π
```

and try again but nothing changed, it still complains `Missing character: There is no π in font cmu10!`.
I also tried the ecrm1000 font as advised by [this answer regarding xetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296616/questions-regarding-the-distinction-between-xetex-and-xelatex-and-how-they-relat/296623#296623).
The solution of [downloading a different(?) computer modern unicode font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249446/163047) is not acceptable because it requires installing the fonts into an OS font directory with root permissions, and I will only use default fonts, or fonts that can be included along side the source tex file.

Comment: I see nowhere in the linked question and answers a reference to cmu10.

Comment: probably due to ignorance, but I assumed that `CMU Serif` was just a latex equivalent reference to `cmu10`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249446/163047) will work, but you don't need to bother installing the font into your system, all you have to do is copy the `cmunrm.otf` file in the same directory as your source tex file and do this

```
\font\cmu="[cmunrm]" at 10pt
\cmu π
\end
```

run `xetex source.tex` and now it works!