# How to use decimal HTML characters

Tags: characters, html

How do I use decimal based HTML characters such as these:
`&#64337;&#64338;&#64339;&#64340;&#64341;&#64342;&#64343;&#64344;&#64345;`

with a special truetype font that assigns a different symbol for each of the above characters? For simplicity, let's say I want to apply Times New Roman font to obtain following:

ﭑﭒﭓﭔﭕﭖﭗﭘﭙ

Is it possible with LaTeX?

Comment: Hi you might want to have a look at this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex

Comment: I believe that the ways how to do this are covered in the question linked by @ArTourter

Comment: I have actually studied it before the question. Although I am using XETEX, but decimal hmtl characters require something else. Hence the question. Many thanks.

Comment: `\char64337 ` (leave a trailing space)

Comment: @egreg: Do you want to turn your comment into an answer? (or have you reached rep cap today already?)

Answer (score 4):

One can always tell XeTeX to insert a glyph from the current font by its number:

```
\char64337
```

for instance. Leave a trailing space (that will be ignored). So your example is

```
\char64337 \char64338 \char64339 \char64340 \char64341
\char64342 \char64343 \char64344 \char64345
```

(an end-of-line is the same as a space). Actually the trailing space is really necessary only after the last one.

You can also define a macro for this:

```
\newcommand{\Ent}[1]{\char#1 }
```

so you can avoid spaces

```
\Ent{64337}\Ent{64338}\Ent{64339}\Ent{64340}\Ent{64341}%
\Ent{64342}\Ent{64343}\Ent{64344}\Ent{64345}
```

or even do it by giving a list of numbers:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Entities}{>{\SplitList{,}}m}{\ProcessList{#1}{\Ent}}

\newcommand{\Ent}[1]{\char#1 }
```

and your input can be simply

```
\Entities{64337,64338,64339,64340,64341,64342,64343,64344,64345}
```