# Tombstone symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

Unicode offers a thin rectangular symbol ▮ instead of the usual square to indicate the end of a proof (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_proof). Is this by any chance available in LaTeX?

Comment: I am confused: You link to a Wikipedia article, where I can read: “In AMS-LaTeX, the symbol is automatically appended at the end of a proof environment `\begin{proof} ... \end{proof}`. It can also be obtained from the commands `\qedsymbol` or `\qed` (the latter causes the symbol to be right aligned).”

Comment: The one provided by AMS is a square instead of a thin rectangle.

Comment: You could make use of the answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34608/14100 along with the unicode U+220E from your link (maybe)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`bbding`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bbding) package offers you `\Rectangle`, `\RectangleBold`, and `\RectangleThin`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbding}

\begin{document}
\Rectangle\quad\RectangleBold\quad\RectangleThin
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here they are in action in a `proof` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bbding}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\Rectangle}
\begin{proof}Test text text text text text text text text text\end{proof}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\RectangleBold}
\begin{proof}Test text text text text text text text text text\end{proof}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\RectangleThin}
\begin{proof}Test text text text text text text text text text\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `pifont` package offers two options through `\ding{121}` and `\ding{122}`; the `marvosym` package has `\Rectsteel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\begin{document}

% require pifont
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ding{121}}
\begin{proof}Test text text text text text text text text text\end{proof}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ding{122}}
\begin{proof}Test text text text text text text text text text\end{proof}
% require marvosym
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\Rectsteel}
\begin{proof}Test text text text text text text text text text\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to, you can scale the symbol using `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package.

Without using additional packages, you can use `\rule` to define your own symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand\TombStone{\rule{.5ex}{2ex}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\TombStone}
\begin{proof}Test text text text text text text text text text\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I got the following error when running your code, and this happens even when I have reinstalled the package using my TeX Live Utility....
!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file bbding10): Font bbding10 at 720 not found
Is there any way around this? Sorry I am new to using LaTeX

Comment: @hwhm you're missing fonts. Anyway, I gave you a package-free alternative in my updated answer.