# Can't overwrite Unicode character definition

Tags: unicode

I want this Unicode symbol `〈`, left-pointing angle bracket, to be interpreted as `\langle`.

On TeX Live on my Mac, I tried this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2329}{\langle}

\begin{document}
$ 〈  $
\end{document}
```

which produces this error:

```
./foo.tex:7: Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 9001 = U+2329,
(ucs)                possibly declared in uni-35.def.
(ucs)                Type H to see if it is available with options.
Unicode character 9001 = U+2329:
Unicode character 9001 = U+2329:
LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET
BRA
Character available with following options:
   postscript.
```

But I don't want to use the option `postscript`, I just want to define that Unicode character 2329 should emit `\langle`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The U+2329 character is deprecated by Unicode; according to the specs, U+3008 should be used. However, `ucs` supports this one only by enabling the options `cjkbg5` or `cjkjis`. I'm not sure why you need `ucs`, can you explain?

Comment: I get the same results for U+3008.  I use `usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}`  because it conveniently defines a host of Unicode symbol for math, particularly Greek letters. I tried enabling cjkjis, but that just broke Unicode support in different ways.

Comment: @egreg, for mathematical use, shouldn’t U+27e8 “⟨” and U+2789 “⟩” (Mathematical Left/Right Angle Bracket) be preferred?

Comment: @J.C.Salomon Probably you're right.

Comment: It's 2013. Please use a Unicode-aware TeX engine, i.e. [tag:XeTeX] or [tag:LuaTeX].

Comment: @egreg Tried those also; no luck.

Comment: @MartinSchröder  I'm collaborating with people that I can't expect to update their engines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `newunicodechar` package, but not with the `utf8x` option to `inputenc`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{〈}{\langle}

\begin{document}
$〈$
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to use `ucs` and `utf8x` (which I can't recommend), you have to load `ucs` with the Postscript option. The definition associated to U+2329 is however faulty, because it produces nothing even when loading `pifont`, that seems required. I provide a workaround.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[postscript]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \sbox0{\let\Pisymbol\relax〈}% this loads uni-35.def and defines the character
  \@namedef{u-postscript-9001}#1{\langle}% we can now change the definition
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a〈b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, in my actual document, I wish to use also ucs, which requires inputenc with utf8**x**.  And besides, I still desperately wish to know why my original approach did not work.

Comment: Thanks. I'll drop my insistence on using `ucs` and define the symbols I need by hand, using your example above.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2329}{bad}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{9001}{okay}
\begin{document}
$ 〈  $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [math mode - ucs clashes with DeclareUnicodeChar? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127975/ucs-clashes-with-declareunicodechar/620231#620231)