# ucs clashes with DeclareUnicodeChar?

Tags: math-mode, unicode, dvi-mode

I'm forced to work with `latex`, and want to make use of unicode chars in math. So I write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B7}{\cdot}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\begin{document}
$a · b$
\end{document}
```

But it gives:

```
aΔb
```

Is there a way to `DeclareUnicodeChars` after `ucs`?

---

The `ucs` manual has something to say about `DeclareUnicodeChars`:

```
Several options have a special hardcoded meaning:
...
Every character you define in your document using \DeclareUnicodeCharacter
has the option document. This option is activated per
default having the priority 1000, therefore manually declared characters take
precedence over all other characters, unless some other option has explicitly
gotten a higher priority.
...
```

So I tried the way I understood it:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter[document]{B7}{\cdot}
```

and

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B7}[document]{\cdot}
```

but it doesn't work.

---

Also tried:

```
\DeclareUnicodeOption{document}
```

and it also doesn't work.

**Edit**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B7}{\cdot} % U+00B7 = cdot
$a · b$
\end{document}
```

Gives:

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   B
l.10 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B7}{\cdot}
                                           % U+00B7 = cdot
```

Also after reading `ucs` sources I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\uc@dclc{183}{mathletters}{\ensuremath{\cdot}}%·

\begin{document}
$a · b$
\end{document}
```

but it gives:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 \uc
       @dclc{183}{mathletters}{\ensuremath{\cdot}}%·
```

Comment: You have to use the option `utf8x` rather than `utf8` in order to use `ucs`. Moreover the call of `ucs` with explicit options such as `mathletters` should precede the call to `inputenc`.

Comment: Your last try should work if you enclose the line containing `\uc@dclc` with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht (I already mentioned that in the newly posted answer)

Comment: I saw that after having posted my comment and I gave your answer +1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Life is much easier without ucs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B7}{\cdot}

\begin{document}
$a · b$
\end{document}
```

But with ucs you simply have to use the correct decimal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{183}{\cdot}

\begin{document}
$a · b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep -- probably it's not hard to define all the chars by hand.

Comment: @adobe ucs works too see my edit, but I don't like it. It does everything a bit different than the standard inputenc and you never know if it will clash with some package (like biblatex).

Comment: The second code does not work anymore (I noted this after a release_upgrade from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20 with accordingly updated TeX versions)? `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` seems to be an undefined contrl sequence in this combo. Removing any of the three preamble lines compiles with warnings (and perhaps not the desired result)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen well as I wrote: it is easier without ucs. Simply don't use it, it is not compatible with everything (and not really maintained).

Answer (score 8):

Life is even easier with `newunicodechar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{·}{\cdot}

\begin{document}
$a·b$
\end{document}
```

If you want to retain the default definition (`\textperiodcentered`) in text mode, then type

```
\newunicodechar{·}{\ifmmode\cdot\else\textperiodcentered\fi}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the last example you could use `makeatletter` and `makeatother`. See latex2e.pdf for documentation of those commands.

> The second code does not work anymore (I noted this after a release_upgrade from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20 with accordingly updated TeX versions)? `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` seems to be an undefined contr[o]l sequence in this combo. Removing any of the three preamble lines compiles with warnings (and perhaps not the desired result)

*Source: [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127975/ucs-clashes-with-declareunicodechar/620231#comment1455815_127984)*

In such cases, this solution will still work.

Not that I recommend using this package (see package comparison: [utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13067/250119)), but there are some issues about normal `utf8` that I'm figuring out.

```latex
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\uc@dclc{183}{mathletters}{\ensuremath{\cdot}}%·
% use {default} instead of {mathletters} to make it work in e.g. text mode
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$a · b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `utf8` is actively maintained by the LaTeX team and has a GitHub site for submitting issue reports. On the contrary, nobody has touched `ucs` for several years.

Comment: Without knowing the TeX Live version that's deployed, it's impossible to give advice; `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` is defined in the kernel starting at least from 2018-04-06. For previous releases, you need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.