# How do I get normal \mapsto and \colon symbols when using unicode-math?

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I am using the `unicode-math` package with XeLaTeX. It works well, but it is making some of my characters look weird. Specifically, the code

> `f \colon x \mapsto x^2`

looks different from normal. Normally, it looks like this:

[image: Without unicode-math]

However, when I use `unicode-math`, it looks like this:

[image: With unicode-math]

In the second image, the space between the dots in the `\colon` is too small. Also, the vertical bar on the `\mapsto` is too large and the horizontal bar is too short. How can I fix this?

I also had a similar issue with `\mathbb{R}` looking different, but when I googled a solution to that I found [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/360607/296881) with [this working solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360612/296881). Is there anyway to do something similar for my problem with `\colon` and `\mapsto`?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\[f\colon x\mapsto x^2\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site:  please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Here we have no idea what you are doing other than using `unicode-math`, there is no information about fonts etc.

Comment: Apologies, I am new to tex.stackexchange. I have not done anything with fonts. I edited in the code I used in another file to isolate the issue, as the issue still persists with only the code that I edited in.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few aspects to mention: `unicode-math` uses

1. U+2236 RATIO for the colon in math mode;
2. U+21A6 RIGHTWARDS ARROW FROM BAR for `\mapsto`;
3. the `amsmath` definition of `\colon` (not simply `\mathpunct`).

To the contrary, legacy 8-bit LaTeX uses

1. the text colon also in math mode;
2. the combination `\mapstochar`+`\rightarrow` to build `\mapsto`;
3. `\mathpunct:` for `\colon` (actually a different definition, but the effect is the same).

It's a job for the font designers to decide the shape for U+2236 and U+21A6. For strange reasons, the designers of Latin Modern Math decided that U+2236 has width 9.77pt, less than U+2192 RIGHTWARDS ARROW (used for `\rightarrow`) that has width 10pt (at natural size of the font). The same choice is done by NewCMMath.

You can restore the legacy behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{legacysymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\legacymapstochar}{\mathrel}{legacysymbols}{"37}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  % use \mapstochar\rightarrow for \mapsto
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\mapsto}{}{\legacymapstochar\rightarrow}%
  % use the text colon for \colon as math punctuation
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\colon}{}{\Umathchar"6 "0 "3A\relax}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
f\colon x\mapsto x^2 \\
f\colon x\rightarrow x^2
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked, thank you!

Comment: By the way, how can I adapt this to other characters? I am also running into the same difficulty with `\therefore` and am having trouble adapting this to fix that.

Comment: @wwjwjwjwj Don’t use `\therefore`. It might be useful at the blackboard, not in print. And, in general, don’t be too attached to particular shapes.

Comment: Of course, I would not use `\therefore` for anything official, but I also use LaTeX for my notes in which I use `\therefore` a lot. I guess you are right, I should not be too attached to the shape, but I still would prefer to know how to adapt this solution to arbitrary characters incase I need it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the math colon is re-designed in Unicode math fonts (at the slot U+2236) depends on the typographical rule that all math operators and symbols should be vertically centered at math axis (like +, -, \to, \mapsto, \sum). The text colon doesn't meet this requirement as you can see in the pictures where the legacy math font is used. If you realize this, the Unicode math result may start to seem better to you.

[image: uniclon]