# Allow consecutive subscripts/superscripts for UTF-8 typing

Tags: unicode, subscripts, superscripts

Is is possible to allow consecutive subscripts/superscripts? I’m discovering the joy of typing UTF-8 characters easily from my keyboard (thanks bépo) and I’d love to be able to type `x²ˣ` instead of `x^{2x}`, however if I define my characters like:

```
\newunicodechar{²}{^2}
\newunicodechar{ˣ}{^x}
```

then LaTeX would complain about the fact that I have two consecutive superscripts. Is there a workaround?

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{²}{^2}
\newunicodechar{ˣ}{^x}
\begin{document}

$x²ˣ > 0$

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618428/250119 yes if you try **really** hard.

Comment: you could define `²` like `'` to look ahead so `x²ˣ` is `x^{2x}` but I woudn't

Comment: @user202729 thanks but it does not explain how to do in with pdflatex, which is the point of this question.

Comment: but my answer there works for PDFLaTeX read carefully...

Comment: ohh good point, thanks a lot, I stopped reading when I saw `A similar algorithm is possible in PDFTeX, but it needs some adaptation because each Unicode character (in UTF-8) corresponds to multiple tokens in PDFTeX. (not included)`… but seems like this is an outdated statement. This works great indeed. Is is the solution you had in mind @DavidCarlisle a simpler approach is possible?

Comment: as I say I wouldn't use superscript characters at all. Perhaps a simple `\newunicodechar{ˣ}{{}^x}`  is good enough, it depends what you want `²ˣ` to mean

Comment: @tobiasBora Okay fixed that one. // Not that I'm aware of, but just copy that 270 lines into your preamble and forget about it.

Comment: I've been intending to wrap the thing into a package but never get the effort to actually release it. // Also TeX is a **really** low-level language with a **very** limited set of "built-in functions", so implementation of anything nontrivial must necessarily be long.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you had a simple fix @DavidCarlisle. So I’m curious, would you also recommend `x^\prime` instead of `x'`? :-P To me, `x⁰ ⊕ x¹` is easier to read and faster to type than `x^0 \oplus x^1`.

Comment: @user202729 Ok thanks a lot!

Comment: I wouldn't even know how to type `x¹` :-)  but that superscript  mathematically a 1, I'd want to find it when searching for `1` in my editor. this does not apply for `\prime` as that is never used full size

Comment: "Oh ok, I thought you had a simple fix" well it is simple, it just depends whether you consider it a fix

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hum, it might just mean that we should improve our editors and keyboards to better handle utf-8 characters :-P Ahah, then thanks for the "fix" ;-)

Comment: specifically `x{}^2{}^x` isn't an error and may (or may not) be mathematically better than `x^{2x}` depending if it is a single superscript or a list of superscript indexes like tensor notation

Comment: Ohh sorry I did not realized that `\newunicodechar{ˣ}{{}^x}` would not produce an error, my mistake. So the formating is slightly different as it adds a small space, but it’s indeed an interesting simple solution. Note however that it would not handle correctly stuff like `2ᵃᵇ_{c}` as c would be below the b and not the a.

Comment: sorry but you are using symbols based on the *look* and not on the meaning. Math can not be represented simply by a chain of utf8 chars, as it is two dimensional and uses font variants. If you try to make the input more simple and visually pleasing you loose formatting options.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don’t understand why using `β` instead of `\beta` emphasis more the meaning. Similarly, `\oplus` does not give any information on the meaning, it only says "put a plus in an o shape", so to me it’s not better than ⊕. Similarly, many symbols have a well established meaning: nobody uses `\plus`, instead of `+`: so why can’t I type`⊕` to denote an addition modulo 2 (XOR) instead of `\oplus`? Similarly, the integral, sum, product… symbols are well established. And nothing prevents someone interested to change the symbols to redefine ⊕ to print another symbol.

Comment: there is no problem with ⊕ or +, the beta depends, perhaps you actually mean , the superscripts are simply wrong as they are never used in unicode math.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What do you mean? Quoting the documentation of the unicode-math package "You may, if you wish, use Unicode subscripts and superscripts in your source document. For basic expressions, the use of these characters can make the input more readable. Adjacent sub- or super-scripts will be concatenated into a single expression." https://texlive.mycozy.space/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf

Comment: they make the input more *readable* but nothing more. Unlike ⊕ they are not the symbol used in the output, they only look similar.