# An extensive list of LaTeX symbols and Unicode equivalents?

Tags: unicode

I want an extensive list of unicode symbols and their corresponding TeX commands. The unicode symbols must be text, not images.

The first two columns [from this source](http://www.johndcook.com/math_symbols.html) (partly reproduced below) are exactly what I'm looking for, but I'd like a more extensive list.

| Symbol | TeX |
| --- | --- |
| ¬ | \neg |
| ± | \pm |
| · | \cdot |
| → | \to |
| ⇒ | \Rightarrow |
| ⇔ | \Leftrightarrow |
| ∀ | \forall |
| ∂ | \partial |

Comment: What about the [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive)? It already contains quite a lot of symbols from a huge variety of packages. But sure, it is a PDF which is maybe not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found one here: https://github.com/joom/latex-unicoder.vim/blob/master/autoload/unicoder.vim. It's quite usable. A glimpse:

```
\ '\upepsilon'                  : 'ε',
\ '\zeta'                       : 'ζ',
\ '\eta'                        : 'η',
\ '\theta'                      : 'θ',
\ '\iota'                       : 'ι',
\ '\kappa'                      : 'κ',
\ '\lambda'                     : 'λ',
\ '\mu'                         : 'μ',
\ '\nu'                         : 'ν',
\ '\xi'                         : 'ξ',
\ '\upomicron'                  : 'ο',
```

Comment: I translated this to [TSV](https://gist.github.com/YodaEmbedding/e57d9b88bae3bd512d5101a19ebd99b7#file-latex_unicode_symbols-tsv) (human readable table) and [JSON](https://gist.github.com/YodaEmbedding/e57d9b88bae3bd512d5101a19ebd99b7#file-latex_unicode_symbols-json).

Answer (score 16):

If you mean the list of symbols defined by `unicode-math`, here's a way to get it with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=literal}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\linespread{1.3}\small
\def\UnicodeMathSymbol#1#2#3#4{\texttt{#1 \string#2}\quad$
  \ifx#2\sqrt
    #2{\mbox{\space}}
  \else
    \ifx#2\not
      #2^^^^2062
    \else
      \ifdefined#2
        #2{\space}
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  $\\}
\noindent\input{unicode-math-table}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The file basically reads `unicode-math-table` and shows the Unicode point, the associated command and the symbol. The list goes on for 24 two column pages, I show only the first lines

[image]

Comment: @KennyLJ Just compile the given source with XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/data/unimathsymbols.txt) has just such a table. (Note: sourceforge.net has set the wrong character encoding, you may need to save the text file to disk and open it with a text editor for the unicode characters to show up properly.  The second and third columns seem to be are pretty much what you're looking for.)  For example, one section of the table soon after the ASCII range looks like this:

```
000A2^¢^\cent^^N^mathord^wasysym^= \mathcent (txfonts), cent
000A3^£^\pounds^\sterling^N^mathord^-fourier -omlmathit^= \mathsterling (txfonts), POUND SIGN, fourier prints a dollar sign
000A4^¤^^^N^mathord^^t \currency (wasysym), curren
000A5^¥^\yen^\yen^N^mathord^amsfonts^YEN SIGN
000A6^¦^^^N^mathord^^brvbar (vertical)
000A7^§^^^N^mathord^^sect
000A8^¨^\spddot^^D^mathord^amsxtra^Dot /die, alias for 0308
000AC^¬^\neg^\neg^U^mathord^^= \lnot, NOT SIGN
000AE^®^\circledR^^X^mathord^amsfonts^REGISTERED SIGN
000AF^¯^^^D^mathord^^macr, alias for 0304
000B0^°^^^N^mathord^^deg
000B1^±^\pm^\pm^V^mathbin^^plus-or-minus sign
000B2^²^^^N^mathord^^sup2
000B3^³^^^N^mathord^^sup3
000B4^´^^^N^mathord^^acute, alias for 0301
000B5^µ^\Micro^^N^mathalpha^wrisym^= \tcmu (mathcomp), t \textmu (textcomp), # \mathrm{\mu} (omlmathrm), # \muup (kpfonts mathdesign), MICRO SIGN
000B6^¶^^^N^mathord^^para (paragraph sign, pilcrow)
000B7^·^^\cdotp^B^mathbin^^# \cdot, x \centerdot, b: MIDDLE DOT
000B9^¹^^^N^mathord^^sup1
000BC^¼^^^N^mathord^^frac14
000BD^½^^^N^mathord^^frac12
000BE^¾^^^N^mathord^^frac34
000BF^¿^^^P^^^iquest
000D7^×^\times^\times^B^mathbin^^MULTIPLICATION SIGN, z notation Cartesian product
000F0^ð^\eth^\matheth^^mathalpha^amssymb arevmath^eth
000F7^÷^\div^\div^B^mathbin^^divide sign
```

Comment: I'm getting weird symbols though instead of the unicode character. Example: `00393^Î“^\Gamma^\upGamma^A^mathalpha^-literal^= \Gamma (-slantedGreek), = \mathrm{\Gamma}, capital gamma, greek`

Comment: That's because sourceforge.net has set the wrong encoding for the text file.  If you save it to disk and then open it with a text editor that supports unicode, the unicode characters should be visible.  (edited post to clarify.)