# U+2234 not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: errors, miktex, unicode, ghostscript

I am using Doxygen to document my C code project. My C source files are saved with UTF-8 encoding. Within some of the files I have mathematical symbols, such as this line:

```
∴ ∀ FOO ∈ ℕ ≤ BAR
```

The symbols are copy-pasted from the fileformat.info website so are definitely the correct UTF-8 characters. My doxygen build uses a config file (encoded in UTF-8) that tells it to produce UTF-8 encoded latex output. It also instructs it to add `amsmath` and `amssymb`

The Doxygen build runs without errors or warnings

Yet when I attempt to build the latex it fails for:

> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd") [1{C:/Users/Toby/App
>   Data/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] [2] [1] [2]
>   Chapter 1.
>   (group__pmb.tex
>
> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char Ôê┤ (U+2234)
>   (inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
>
> See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.12 ...+E+L+O+W+E+R+B+I+TS))\mbox{]} Ôê┤
>                                                      ÔêÇ A+D+D+R+_++N+...
>
> ?

It seems to error on the first symbol (∴) that it encounters.

I'm not a TeX person, I just want to document my C program well (which worked on my last PC, of course running older versions of all software involved). What more can I do to get it to understand the symbol characters?

I am using the latest version of MiKTeX (64-bit) and ghostscript (32-bit)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I hope those unicode characters are not outside of comments or removed preprocessing tokens because the behaviour will be undefined and your compiler may order you pizza, or possibly format your hard drive.

Comment: Why not just use XeLaTeX?

Comment: Doxygen produces latex output and build files, I've tried adjusting to XeLaTeX but it doesn't really work.

Comment: @cat Mmm pizza :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2234}{\therefore}
```

to your document preamble. How to do it for Doxygen I don't know. You need also `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

You can somewhat automate the correspondence between Unicode point and command name with something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\UnicodeMathSymbol[4]{%
  \ifnum#1>"FF
    \expandafter\DeclareUnicodeCharacter\expandafter{\@gobble#1}{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\input{unicode-math-table}

\begin{document}

$∴$

\end{document}
```

based on the assumption that the command name offered by `unicode-math-table` is the same as the `amssymb` name.

Comment: Maybe also `\ensuremath`? Not sure if Doxygen would be smart enough to put the symbols in math mode.

Comment: Ah I meant I have `amssymb`, not `asmsymb`, d'oh. Will I need to do this for every UTF-8 symbol that I use? surely if LaTex supports UTF-8 symbols then it should recognise them without this  for each symbol?

Comment: @WillieWong The error message seems to be in a math formula; I wouldn't use `\ensuremath` anyway, because the symbol is math and should stay in math.

Comment: @Toby no, the utf8 support means that it will decode the utf8 encoding and know that you want U+2234, it does not define all the thousands of characters that could be accessed by number and allocate a font for each one. but an alternative would be to use xelatex and unicode-math which uses opentype math fonts which do have a large range of math characters in a single font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, where can I find the names to use for each character (e.g. the `\therefore`)? Or do they match the UTF-8 names? Bonus question: How does one know which package to `use`? I selected `amsmath` based on it's name but haven't a notion what it really provides - or any of the other packages TBH, is there a canonical listing with explanation somewhere?

Comment: you have to just know. For math characters the ams* packages almost certainy covers what you need but if it was say U+A880 I'd have no idea what font would support that, other than google for information, but perhaps you would do better with xelatex (or lualatex) and just use unicode-math` package but that's really not the subject of this question/answer

Comment: @Toby: If you don't know the LaTeX commands, [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) can be handy. Alternatively, [egreg's answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162385/an-extensive-list-of-latex-symbols-and-unicode-equivalents) can also be useful for looking things up if you know the unicode.