# How to print out Unicode character and command of every character in book

Tags: symbols, unicode

I would like to find a [table of Unicode characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162385/an-extensive-list-of-latex-symbols-and-unicode-equivalents_) mapped to LaTeX commands. Specifically everything [here](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) mapped to the unicode equivalent.

I found a partial list [here](https://github.com/joom/latex-unicoder.vim/blob/master/autoload/unicoder.vim) but it doesn't include many basic ones such as `Æ` as `\AE`.

So to rephrase the related questions, I'm wondering how I could iterate through all the commands in a package and print out the symbols and their Unicode equivalents myself. Or if it can't print the Unicode code for the symbol (like `U+0000`), then just printing the actual character enough so that I can copy-paste it into a text file out from the PDF, and then I can just write some code to transform it to the Unicode equivalent.

But basically I would like to generate a big list of all the commands from that [pdf](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), and their either symbol form or Unicode form.

Comment: you could start with /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex  (or an equivalent place on your installation)

Comment: Not really sure what that means. `cat /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-tble.tex
cat: /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex: No such file or directory`

Comment: Do you have a full TL distribution?

Comment: do you have unicode-math package installed? the file is part of that. the full path is just the default texlive location

Comment: `\alpha` is not even listed in that package, I am looking for more than just that. https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math