# How to print commands and their output in a PDF document and to the terminal/console

Tags: macros, symbols

I found a [big list of symbols](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and the source [here](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/SYMLIST). I would like to simply do this: place each command on a new line, and evaluate the command in the first column, and print the command in the second column. Like this:

```
α \A
β \B
...
```

I just made those commands up, but essentially that. Print the output next to the command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\A --- \begin{verbatim} A \end{verbatim}

\aa --- \begin{verbatim} aa \end{verbatim}

\AA --- \begin{verbatim} AA \end{verbatim}

\AAaleph --- \begin{verbatim} AAaleph \end{verbatim}

\AAayin --- \begin{verbatim} AAayin \end{verbatim}

\AAbeth --- \begin{verbatim} AAbeth \end{verbatim}

\AAcht --- \begin{verbatim} AAcht \end{verbatim}

\AAdaleth --- \begin{verbatim} AAdaleth \end{verbatim}

\AAhe --- \begin{verbatim} AAhe \end{verbatim}

\AAhelmet --- \begin{verbatim} AAhelmet \end{verbatim}

\AAheth --- \begin{verbatim} AAheth \end{verbatim}

\AAkaph --- \begin{verbatim} AAkaph \end{verbatim}

\AAlamed --- \begin{verbatim} AAlamed \end{verbatim}

\Aaleph --- \begin{verbatim} Aaleph \end{verbatim}

\AApe --- \begin{verbatim} AApe \end{verbatim}

\AAqoph --- \begin{verbatim} AAqoph \end{verbatim}

\AAresh --- \begin{verbatim} AAresh \end{verbatim}

\AAsade --- \begin{verbatim} AAsade \end{verbatim}

\Aayin --- \begin{verbatim} Aayin \end{verbatim}

\AAyod --- \begin{verbatim} AAyod \end{verbatim}

\AB --- \begin{verbatim} AB \end{verbatim}

\Abeth --- \begin{verbatim} Abeth \end{verbatim}

\ac --- \begin{verbatim} ac \end{verbatim}

\AC --- \begin{verbatim} AC \end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

But it didn't work.

It would also be interesting to know, perhaps preferable, to log the output to the console as it is compiling. Wondering how to do that.

Comment: your question isn't that clear (you can look at the source of the file to see how it prints command names, but also how are we supposed to use the supplied example, since almost all the commands are undefined?

Comment: the tex source of the comprehensive symlist is https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/source

Comment: I would also add http://detexify.kirelabs.org/ to the list

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question but this makes a log of

```
\alpha: \mathchar"10B
\beta: \mathchar"10C
\longrightarrow: \long macro:->\DOTSB \protect \relbar \protect \joinrel \right
arrow
```

and output

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\def\zz#1{\par
\typeout{\string#1: \meaning#1}%
\makebox[5cm][l]{\texttt{\string#1}}\mbox{$#1$}\par}

\begin{document}

\zz\alpha
\zz\beta
\zz\longrightarrow
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want the log output to be exactly this: `α \alpha`, not `\alpha: \mathchar"10B`.

Comment: typeout unicode latex

Comment: This isn't working `\def\zz#1{\typeout{\string#1: #1}\texttt{\string#1}:$#1$}`. It shows `\alpha:\alpha` not `\alpha:α`.

Comment: @LancePollard but if  you are using pdflatex to typeset the results there is no unicode definitions involved most of the command differences in the comprehensive symbol document relate to font changes not unicode slots.

Comment: @LancePollard If you are just looking for a mapping between unicode slots and tex names look in unicode-math's  `unicode-math-table.tex` but we had this conversation before https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494340/how-to-print-out-unicode-character-and-command-of-every-character-in-book#comment1248006_494340