# Abstract problem

Tags: errors, abstract

Whenever I try to copy the abstract it gives me the following error:

> (Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:α not set up for use w
>   ith LaTeX.
>
> See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.27 \maketitle)

What should I do?

Comment: Can you supply an MWE?

Comment: @ahmed Just provide an example of your code. Unicode characters are unsupported in plain latex without a few tweaks (`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`). Try typesetting your doc using `xelatex` or reading this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex

Comment: If you are copying the text from some webpage or other pdf file, when you past it into tex file you have to replace those Greek letters by `$\alpha$` for example.