# How to be able to use ∞ in latex document?

Tags: pdftex, unicode, characters

I would like to use the unicode character ∞ in a LaTeX document. I use the default font. If this character is not defined in this font, I can replace it by `$\infty$`.

How can I do that?

I tried to play with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{}{$\infty$}` but did not find what to put in the first argument.

Comment: You should consider using xelatex for this. You can find an answer to your question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34609/22432)

Comment: oh I just see you tagged your question unicode-math are you using that package (and so xetex or luatex) if so DeclareUnicodeCharacter is completely the wrong thing and I will delete my answer.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't use `xetex` not `luatex`.

Comment: I retagged then:-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

∞ is U+221E so you want, for (pdf)teX

```
 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{221E}{\ensuremath{\infty}}
```

Comment: Is there a difference if you use `\ensuremath{\infty}` vs `$\infty$` in that declaration?

Comment: @Alenanno `{$\infty$}` would be wrong, possibilities are what I have or (arguably better) just `{\infty}`   try `$ x < ∞ $` to see the difference:-)