# Unicode characters of unknown language

Tags: unicode

I'm trying to have the following two characters correctly displayed in the PDF output:

[image][image]

According to http://unicode-table.com/, these two characters belong to the Latin Extended-B category, and are used in Slovenian and Croatian.

Here's my minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin,slovene,croatian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

Display \foreignlanguage{latin}{ʠ}

Display \foreignlanguage{latin}{Ǽ}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the second one is easy, just `\'{\AE}`  but the first might be harder to find a font for

Comment: Thanks @David, I realize the second one can be done relatively easily. But I need them both in the document.

Comment: `ʠ` belongs to the “IPA extensions” block; `Ǽ` belongs to the “Latin Extended B” block. Neither is used in Slovenian or Croatian. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_with_hook), the character `ʠ` was withdrawn from IPA in 1993.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of http://detexify.kirelabs.org I found the first letter.

The 2nd is already found by David.

Code example:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone} 
\usepackage{ tipa }
\begin{document}
\texthtq

\'{\AE}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The letters itself don't work, but maybe you find a solution in [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex)

Comment: You also find them in `erewhon` (an extension of `Adobe Utopia`) and `ebgaramond`, in opentype format

Comment: another source for fonts with extensive complements of letters from latin-based alphabets and phonetics is [sil international](http://www.sil.org/).  i don't know about the status of (la)tex support, but am pretty sure that it must exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can put the Unicode symbols directly in your `.tex` file. You just have to load a system font that has the symbols you want. You can check http://www.fileformat.info for [a list of some fonts that include ʠ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02a0/fontsupport.htm) and [a list of some fonts that include Ǽ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/01fc/fontsupport.htm).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}
ʠ Ǽ \sffamily ʠ Ǽ
\end{document}
```

[image]