# Adding special characters Љ Б Д И П و △ ★ ✚ ✠ ✤ ✶ ✸ ❀ ❃ in latex

Tags: pdftex, unicode

I'm autogenerating pdfs via pdflatex and perl and I am having problems in
getting these characters to print in pdflatex: 
 Љ
 Б
 Д
 И
 П
 و
 △
 ★
 ✚
 ✠
 ✤
 ✶
 ✸
 ❀
 ❃

Here is a template of the statments I use with for instance ❃ inserted:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[german,english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
pdftex,
bookmarks=true,
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksnumbered=true,
pdfstartpage=1
]
{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}


\title{\bfseries Test}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\section*{1}

❃ 

\end{document}
```

I have installed the language packs on Ubuntu via

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-european texlive-lang-cyrillic texlive-lang-german texlive-lang-greek
```

I think Љ Б Д И П are cyrillic but if I use

```
\usepackage[german,english,greek,russian]{babel}
```

Then the greek 
 Α
 Γ
 Δ
 Ε
 Η
 Ι
 Λ
 Μ
 Ν
 Ο
 Ρ
 Σ
 Τ
 Υ
 Χ
 Ω (that are also included in my character set) will fail while Љ Б Д И П will succeed. So it seems that "greek and russia" are incompatible ?
Is there a easy way out of this?
Is it possible to get "Љ Б Д И П و △ ★ ✚ ✠ ✤ ✶ ✸ ❀ ❃" encoded by some means without adding "russia" to babel? *And where are the other symbols defined*? ❀ for instance is U+2740. I think I have to use:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2740}{ ... }
```

However then I have to know the latex version of ❀.

Comment: What's the default language of your document?

Comment: The default language is german

Comment: Are you able to use LuaTeX or XeTeX? With LuaTeX, you would use the `fontspec` package instead of `fontenc`, `polyglossia` instead of `babel`, and always utf-8 encoding. Then you could simply paste the characters from a character map, as long as you have them in a font. Or you could call them by Unicode. It does not matter which language(s) you specify, since this method is inherently multi-lingual. Dingbats OK too.

Comment: Do you need all those packages to reproduce not printing something? Please make your code minimal. Also, you probably want to include all the characters you need so that people have a proper test case to work with.

Comment: Off-topic: `hyperref` should  be loaded ***late***.

Comment: RobtA: I rather not switch to something other than pdflatex, I use javascript embedded in pdf and I guess I would have to start from scratch. In the worst case I will generate jpgs for those chars I cannot get right. Cfr: i have a excel sheet with text containing the extra chars, I scan it with perl and generate pdfs for each row. You are right that not all packages are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I had to do:

- Packages

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,landscape,enabledeprecatedfontcommands]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}     
\usepackage[russian,arabic,farsi,greek,german]{babel}
\usepackage{arabtex}
```

- Symbols △ ★ ✚ ✠ ✤ ✶ ✸ ❀ ❃: Part comes from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters

  I use pifont and \ding

Code:

```
\usepackage{pifont}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10048}{ \ding{95} }
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10051}{ \ding{93} }
...
```

- For the cyrillic characters Љ Б Д И П and greek character Α..Ω :

Code:

```
\textcyrillic{П}
\textgreek{Ω}
```

- Symbol و : Part comes from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Arabic_script and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArabTeX

Code:

```
   \RL{w}
```

Conculsion:

1. german, english are handled by babel
2. cyrillic symbols are handled by \textcyrillic{}
3. greek symbols are handled by \textgreek{}
4. arabic symbols are handled by \RL{}
5. wingding entries are handled by pifont, \ding and \DeclareUnicodeCharacter

Notes:

1. Languages in the babel usepackage statement seem to override each other. Therefore \textcyrillic and \textgreek is used.
2. I use utf8x for inputenc
3. When using arabtex I also have to add enabledeprecatedfontcommands

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is use xelatex\lualatex with a font with all the  glyphs that you need:

---

[image: mwe]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

Adding special characters 
Љ Б Д И П و △ ★ ✚ ✠ ✤ ✶ ✸ ❀ ❃ 
in \LaTeX

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this is not the case of most fonts, so, depending on the font style and symbols what you need, it could be a good idea just change the main font, as in the example, or change the font only in macros to type selected symbols with a different font, or obtain these symbols of packages as `bbding` and `amssymb` (that provide commands for at least some stars and crosses of the example), o even use macros were the symbol is supplied simply by a small image (~ 1em or so ...). If the image is a vectorial draw (svg) exported to pdf, the result is perfect.