# How can type special shape of some characters?

Tags: arabic, xepersian, persian

In some languages (I mean persian or arabic) one character may has different 
shapes according to the next character. For example "به " and "ب  ", in first one ب has one shape and in second another shape.

I need ب in its connected shape but no character must appear after it. I already test `\phantom` and some other tricks but none of them works.

Comment: In LuaTex "\char 65169" solves the problem.  65169=FE91, for more information see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a character on the Arabic Keyboard `ـ` it is on Shift+J (on my keyboard). It sets the character `ARABIC TATWEEL U+0640` which allows you to have all characters in connected form like بـ or ـه .

I know that this character has also another purpose but I have seen it used in books precisely to achieve what you are looking for (and also this is how I usually do it).

Comment: I can not type it by keyboard but when write it using `\char 1600` it works! thanks a lot!