# Computer Modern Unicode

Tags: unicode

I'm wondering whether there is way to get combined diacritics like `oͮ`, i.e. o + `u+036E` with the CMU font family (CMU Sans Serif}. It doesn't seem to work.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Sans Serif}

\begin{document}

It doesn’t seem to work: oͮ

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Oliver

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex). Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: @jjdb The example is *already* using `fontspec`, so it only runs with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. This is not at all similar to the question you mention.

Comment: It won't work. The glyph is not in the font. If you look in the log-file you will see a message `Missing character: There is no ͮ (U+036E) in font CMUSansSerif` (with lualatex, xelatex has a slightly different wording).

Comment: Are you sure you want U+036E (COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER V) and not a combining caron, that is U+030C?

Comment: @egreg ok. I'll delete the second comment then. The first has some references to Xetex etc.

Answer (score 3):

The CMU Sans Serif font has no U+036E (COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER V). You can emulate it, but this needs a different way to type it in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{CMU Sans Serif}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sv}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \check@mathfonts
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \fontsize{\ssf@size}{\z@}\selectfont v\cr
      \noalign{\vskip0.05ex}
      #1\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

This is “o with caron”: ǒ

This is “o with small v accent”: \sv{o}

\end{document}
```

I added the “o with caron”, which is perhaps what you actually want.

[image]