# Changing typesetting language without command

Tags: languages

I have a problem with typesetting LaTeX using both Greek and English characters. All this time, I've been using the `polyglossia`+`fontspec` packages which allowed me to change between Greek and English just by changing language on my keyboard.

This combination allows me to choose the fonts that I will use, but when letters in math mode mix with letters outside of math mode, the result is not so aesthetic. A solution to this is to substitute all math mode letter with `\textrm`, but I hope to find something less tiresome.

I actually want to change the font that I am using to, say, Kerkis. What I found online is that I have to add the following two packages

```
\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Adding these two packages (while removing `fontspec`) makes the file to not even compile.

So, my question is: how can I change the typesetting font in and out of math mode (let's say to Kerkis) while keeping the ability to change language without having to use a TeX command?

Edit: I used the `mathspec` package instead of `fontspec`, downloaded Kerkis fonts and manually added them using these:

```
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
\setmainfont{KerkisSans}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin)[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Kerkis}
\setmathsfont(Greek)[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Kerkis}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
```

Still, it feels like a half-measure since I'm feeling like I should just load a "Kerkis" package or something that would do the job for me, shouldn't I?

Comment: When the alfabet is Latin, glyphs in math mode should also look different as those in text mode.

Comment: Please give a real, compilable example of font combinations you find unsatisfactory.

Comment: @mico any font i try in greek language except from the latex defaults does not seem fine.

Comment: Does my answer in this question helps? :(https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/396528/120578 ) It is about XeLaTeX for these languages and you can chose font for math and for text at any time...

Comment: Nice approach but I do not know if it answers my question exactly. I still only use greek letters outside of math mode. For math mode I restrict myself to latin characters.

Comment: You may didn't checked my answer with your code... I just suggesting using latin letters in math mode for greek... But it is not necessary. See my answer

Comment: I suggest an edit to the title close to yours but more accurate to help future users: "switch between English/Greek without command (text and math mode-XeLaTeX) "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I suggested in the comment above:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}%[MnSymbol]{mathspec} %<-No need for this in this example
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setallmainfonts{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
%\newfontfamily\greekfont{Linux Libertine O}

% Definitions of Greek (in math mode)
\def\alpha{α}
\def\beta{β}
\let\oldgamma\gamma %<-see the difference below
\def\gamma{γ}
\def\delta{δ}
\def\epsilon{ε}
\def\zeta{ζ}
\def\eta{η}
\def\theta{θ}
\def\iota{ι}
\def\kappa{κ}
\def\lambda{λ}
\def\mu{μ}
\def\nu{ν}
\def\xi{ξ}
%\def\ο{o}
\def\pi{π}
\def\rho{ρ}
\def\sigma{σ}
\def\tau{τ}
\def\upsilon{υ}
\def\phi{φ}
\def\varphi{ϕ}
\def\chi{χ}
\def\psi{ψ}
\def\omega{ω}
\def\varsigma{ς}
\def\varrho{ϱ}
\def\vartheta{ϑ}

\def\Alpha{Α}
\def\Beta{Β}
\def\Gamma{Γ}
\def\Delta{Δ}
\def\Epsilon{Ε}
\def\Zeta{Ζ}
\def\Eta{Η}
\def\Theta{Θ}
\def\Iota{Ι}
\def\Kappa{Κ}
\def\Lambda{Λ}
\def\Mu{Μ}
\def\Nu{Ν}
\def\Xi{Ξ}
%\def\Ο{O}
\def\Pi{Π}
\def\Rho{Ρ}
\def\Sigma{Σ}
\def\Tau{Τ}
\def\Upsilon{Υ}
\def\Phi{Φ}
\def\Chi{Χ}
\def\Psi{Ψ}
\def\Omega{Ω}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

English text


$$α=\frac{β}{γ_s \text{ or }\oldgamma_s} \text{ or }\alpha=\frac{\beta}{\gamma_\sigma} \text{ and } 6_p$$


\selectlanguage{greek}

Ελληνικό κείμενο εδώ

$$α=\frac{β}{γ_s \text{ or }\oldgamma_s} \text{ or }\alpha=\frac{\beta}{\gamma_\sigma} \text{ and } 6_p$$

\setmainfont{FreeSans}
\selectlanguage{english}

English text


$$α=\frac{β}{γ_s \text{ or }\oldgamma_s} \text{ or }\alpha=\frac{\beta}{\gamma_\sigma} \text{ and } 6_p$$

\selectlanguage{greek}

Ελληνικό κείμενο εδώ

$$α=\frac{β}{γ_s \text{ or }\oldgamma_s} \text{ or }\alpha=\frac{\beta}{\gamma_\sigma} \text{ and } 6_p$$

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

PS: The package `MnSymbol` didn't used here and see the correction on the `\oldgamma` spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the question as 'How to use the same Greek font for maths and text', here is a `unicode-math` package way, with its granularity of approach: use the `range=` option to read in glyphs for one or more of the desired lowercase and uppercase Greek alphabets in the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols unicode block (bold, italic, bold-italic, sans bold, sans bold-italic).

It does give a more consistent look:

[image: greek text and maths]

Direct input is also accepted (e.g., the red capital mu).

This example also sets Greek letter math-style to ISO style, rather than French or English. The maths font is `XITS Math` having its italic Greek and bold-italic Greek math alphabets replaced by the glyphs from the non-math `Noto Serif` italic and bold-italic faces, with `Noto Serif` itself being used for the Greek text font as well.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,varwidth,border=6pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
%\setmathfont{Noto Serif}[range={up/{greek,Greek},it/{greek,Greek},bfit/{greek,Greek}},Colour=blue]%fontface; regular
\setmathfont{Noto Serif Italic}[range=it/{greek,Greek},Colour=blue]
\setmathfont{Noto Serif Bold Italic}[range=bfit/{greek,Greek},Colour=red]
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Noto Serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{greek}
Το \textbf{ηλιακό σύστημα} περιλαμβάνει τον Ήλιο και όλα τα αντικείμενα τα οποία κινούνται σε τροχιά γύρω από αυτόν μέσα στο πεδίο βαρύτητάς του, είτε περιστρεφόμενα άμεσα γύρω από αυτόν είτε κινούμενα σε τροχιές γύρω από άλλα σώματα που κινούνται γύρω από τον Ήλιο. Βρίσκεται στο τοπικό διαστρικό Νέφος, το οποίο ανήκει στην Τοπική Φυσαλίδα, η οποία με τη σειρά της ανήκει στον βραχίονα του Ωρίωνα στο Γαλαξία, σε απόσταση 27.000 ετών φωτός από το κέντρο του. -- \textit{Βικιπαίδεια}
\end{greek}

\[ \alpha^2 + \beta^2 = \gamma^2 \]

\[\Alpha_1 \Beta_1 = 4\Gamma_2 \]

\[ _{\iota} = (_{\alpha}, _{\beta}, _{\gamma})\cdot 4\sin^{2}()\]

\[α=\frac{β}{γ_s \text{ or }\gamma_s} \text{ or }\alpha=\frac{\beta}{\gamma_\sigma} \text{ and } 6_p\]
\ 
\end{document}
```

Unrelated: `polyglossia`, `mathspec` and `unicode-math` all use `fontspec` in the background.