# Spacing of subscripts for inline math

Tags: fonts, spacing, inline, lucida

```
$\sigma_{ij} = \rho\sigma_{i}\sigma_{j}$
```

[image]

Is it just me, or does the spacing look wrong on the right-hand side? The subscripts seem to be too far to the right.

Is there a way to move the subscripts closer, like they are on the left side? Or maybe the spacing looks fine and my eyes play a trick on me? I'm using LuaLaTeX with the Lucida Bright fonts.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I have give an answer with nice results in similar problem here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396528/xelatex-minion-pro-subscript-vertical-alignment/396530#396530. If it solves your problem tell us to mark the question as a duplicate...

Comment: It looks like you're using a Times Roman math font. If this impression is correct, which math font do you employ?

Comment: @Mico I'm using LucidaBrightMathOT, I got the font from TUG a while ago: https://www.tug.org/store/lucida/opentype.html

Comment: opentypemath setting is still very experimental luatex has some settings.. try values of \mathoption noitaliccompensation`  I don't have the font to test

Comment: With XeLaTeX the output is correct.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately none of the three possible options affects in some way the present situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is a bug in LuaTeX. Curiously, if you add an empty atom to the subscript, the kerning is correct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Lucida Bright OT}
\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}

\begin{document}

$\sigma_{ij}=\sigma_{i}\sigma_{j}$ (original)

$\sigma_{ij}=\sigma_{i{}}\sigma_{j{}}$ (with phantoms)

\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, this is the output with XeLaTeX

[image]

Note: apparently LuaTeX 1.09 has fixed the issue, but TeX Live 2018 is bound to LuaTeX 1.07.

Comment: I see a similar spacing issue for `\[ T_{\text{feed}} \]` under LuaLaTeX + Lucida, but not under XeLaTeX + Lucida (nor under pdfTeX). However, it is not corrected by phantoms as for the above.  Is it known whether LuaTeX 1.09 covers this issue also?

Comment: @John Sorry, no idea. I can't run 1.09; it was Ulrike Fischer who did the experiments.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a small negative mu space (f.y.i., a `thinspace: \,` is 3mu):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \sigma_{ij} = \rho\sigma_{\mkern-1 mu i}\sigma_{\mkern-1mu j}
 \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks better, I'll use that if there is no way to correct the spacing document wide.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem of kerning. You could borrow the `subscriptcorrection` code from the [`newtxmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx) package, which I believe is inspired by that from the [`mtpro2`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2) package.

**Edited**: The following code makes the kerning automatic, so you don’t need to add negative spaces each time a “bad-looking” subscript occurs. Since the code is taken from `newtxmath`, the kerning instructions are designed for Times. You might need to make adjustments for Lucida.

```
\makeatletter
% Enable subscript correction
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`\_=\string"8000 \catcode`\_=12\relax}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Subscript correction code
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begingroup
 \catcode`\_=13
 \gdef_{\futurelet\next\s@@b}
\endgroup
\def\s@@b{\ifcat\relax\noexpand\next\expandafter\sb\else
 \expandafter\s@@b@\fi}
\def\s@@b@#1{\sb{\futurelet\next\sb@#1}}
\def\sb@{%
 \ifx\next\space@\def\next@. {\futurelet\next\sb@}\else
  \def\next@.{%
   \ifx\next f\mkern-\tw@ mu\else
   \ifx\next j\mkern-\tw@ mu\else
   \ifx\next p\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   %\ifx\next t\mkern\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next y\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next A\mkern-\tw@ mu\else
   \ifx\next B\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next D\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next H\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next I\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next K\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next L\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next M\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next N\mkern-0.5mu\else
   \ifx\next P\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next X\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi}%
 \fi
 \next@.} 
\makeatother
```

You may adjust the `\@ne`, `\tw@` and `0.5` <del>to your use of font</del> for LucidaBrightMathOT, which are completely *subjective* as they are problems of graphic design.

**Added**: If you wish to add new kerning instruction, for instance for `$\sigma_i$`, then insert `\ifx\next i\mkern-<number>mu\else` before the `\ifx\next j\mkern-\tw@ mu\else` line, *and* add one more `\fi` to that sequence of repeated `\fi`’s. Common choices for `<number>` are `1`, `2` and `3`.

Also, notice that `newtxmath` commented out the kerning instruction for `$_t$`: `%\ifx\next t\mkern\@ne mu\else`.

Comment: Thanks! This improves the j subscript, I'll try adjusting the parameters to get the i right.

Comment: @Florian I added some instructions to help with the kerning of `$_i$`. :)