# Using greek characters in commands' arguments without braces

Tags: greek, arguments

First I want to make clear that I'm a LaTeX beginner, so I'll be detailed because I just have no clue about the origin of my problem. I'm using TeXstudio 2.12.6

I'll provide context: I have been researching how to write greek characters directly in the math mode and having them recognised as so when compiled. I.e., I wanted

```
α = xy^2 + β
```

being recognised exactly as

```
\alpha = xy^2 + \beta
```

Ι finally figured out here how to achieve it: [Type Greek letters in Math Mode using Greek keyboard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396311/type-greek-letters-in-math-mode-using-greek-keyboard), just using the preamble indicated there (it's in the accepted answer):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,dsfont,alphabeta}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
```

Although there's some differences between the original one given in the answer and mine here:

1. the babel package flags were originally `[english, greek]`, while mine here are `[greek,spanish]`: Order in the flags matters and this way spanish is the principal language in my code (as I wanted it to be).
2. I'm using `{amsmath,amssymb,dsfont}` too.
3. I'm using report instead of article.

Now my problem: Recently I've discovered that in math mode when using commands it's not necessary to use braces to encapsulate arguments. In other words, TeXstudio does identify `\binom a b` exactly as `\binom{a}{b}`. BUT, when I use a greek letter in an argument given without braces, it won't compile and pops up this two errors:

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\endgroup (U+3CE)(inputenc) not
>   set up for use with LaTeX. \binom α
>
> Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined(inputenc)
>   in inputencoding `utf8'. \binom α

When writing `\binom α b` in math mode.

Another example: It happens a similar thing when writing `overbrace β` instead of `overbrace{β}` in math mode. (In both cases, `overbrace{β}` and `binom{α}{b}` do work).

Please help. And thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you like to type the commands this way?

Comment: That is (I think) because `α` is a multi-byte unicode character.  Without the grouping, only the first byte is absorbed as the argument, before `inputenc` can sort it out as a multi-byte unicode character.  Keep in mind the concept of unicode characters was developed long after TeX's argument-absorbing mechanisms were in place

Comment: You should *always* type `\binom{x}{y}`. Then your problem vanishes. Typing `\binom x y` as well as `\frac 1 2` easily leads to problems.

Comment: I would add that using the braces is the prescribed TeX syntax.  While sometimes, one can avoid it, such shortcuts should not be encouraged, precisely because they bite you at times like this.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I was just being lazy in writing braces.

Comment: Actually this is possible by e.g. patching `\binom` e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/649020/250119, but then you either have to patch every command or use some "preprocessor" over the whole code which loses synctex -- although this can be mitigated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't get what you'd like. You have to consider that `\binom` takes two arguments and, if a brace doesn't follow, the first argument will be the next token; similarly for the second argument.

## Analysis

When you type `\binom α b`, TeX actually sees

```
\binom <CE><B1> b
```

so it does the same as if it had found

```
\binom{<CE>}{<B1>} b
```

where `<CE>` and `<B1>` represent characters with the indicated hexadecimal code. Remember that TeX doesn't really know about Unicode and UTF-8.

The character `α` is represented in UTF-8 by two bytes (the ones I showed above). The `inputenc` package makes `<CE>` into an active character, whose action is to examine the next byte and take the appropriate action, in this case, being followed by `<B1>` it changes the two bytes into `\alpha` that the package `alphabeta` has redefined to give

```
\TextOrMath{\textalpha}{\mathalpha}
```

So, if `α` appears in math mode, you'll eventually find the same as if typing `\alpha` in the traditional setup.

But the important fact is that `<CE>` ***must*** be followed by another byte so that their ***combination*** points to the right definition. Which doesn't happen if you have `\binom α b`.

## Conclusion

> ***Always*** type braces in that situation. You gain nothing by typing `\binom n k` instead of the clearer `\binom{n}{k}`.

And if you try `$X_\notin$`, you'll learn to also type `$X_{1}`. A good editor will do that for you.

## Addendum: the whole story

Actually the whole thing is a bit more complicated, even the explanation above is substantially correct. If you want to know the whole story, here it is.

Following the expansion of `\binom`, the input `\binom α b` is transformed into

```
\genfrac (){0pt}{}<CE><B1> b
```

and `\genfrac` is a four argument macro, that in turn calls `\@genfrac` and the input becomes

```
\@genfrac\relax\@@abovewithdelims{(){0pt}} <CE><B1> b
```

and finally, since `\@genfrac` is a five argument macro, this becomes

```
{\relax{\begingroup <CE>\endgroup\@@abovewithdelims()0pt <B1>}} b
```

As you see `<CE>` is followed by `\endgroup` and, indeed, the error message is

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ?\endgroup (U+3CE)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

(the question mark represents the prefix `<CE>`). After some other errors you get the same as `\binom{}{b}`, but the fact that `b` appears in the right place is just because of how TeX attempts error recovery for the missing `\endgroup` (that had already been absorbed and discarded in the process of expanding `<CE>`).