# Combining \newunicodechar with delimiter sizes \big, \left, \right, etc

Tags: pdftex, unicode, delimiters, newunicodechar

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{‖}{\ensuremath{\|}}
\begin{document}
$$ ‖x‖ $$
$$ \big‖x\big‖ $$  % Error: Missing delimiter
\end{document}
```

Can we somehow hack `\big` to make it work?

Comment: Somewhat similar to [Using greek characters in commands' arguments without braces - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405037/using-greek-characters-in-commands-arguments-without-braces).

Comment: Side note for OP: [math mode - Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Comment: It'd be very complicated to make a `‖` character automatically determine whether the spacing should be `\mathopen`, `\mathclose`, as a middle bar or a relational operator. However, you might use the paired-math-delimiter commands in `mathtools` for a good shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\ensuremath` makes no sense.

You can make it work with `pdflatex`, but you have to use braces with `\big` or similar commands. Not with `\left` and `\right`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{‖}{\|}

\begin{document}

\[
‖x‖ + \bigl{‖}x\bigr{‖} + \left‖\frac{x}{2}\right‖
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is that `‖` is not a single byte and `\bigl` only absorbs the first one.

**Usual caveats.** `$$` should not be used in LaTeX and `\big` is not the right command for that use case.

On the other hand, `\lVert` and `\rVert` *are* the right commands for that use case.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with `\left` and `\right`. Why shouldn't `\big` be used? What's the difference to using `\bigl` and `\bigr`? Seems like `\big` is the "default" suggestion for delimiter sizes around the web (e.g. [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Brackets_and_Parentheses) or  [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Manual_sizing))

Comment: @Hyperplane try `$\big|-1\big|$` vs `$\bigl|-1\bigr|$`, the l an r variants create proper opening and closing symbol codes and thus the spacing on the minus becomes that of a sign not a binary relation.

Comment: Same problem exists with `‖-x‖` after `\newunicodechar{‖}{\|}`. Compare with this: `\lVert -x \rVert`.

Comment: The description of overleaf and wikibooks on this topic is incorrect.

Comment: @Hyperplane It does work with `\left` and `\right`, without braces. See edit.

Comment: @egreg Huh? Weird I got a compilation error earlier, must've done something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For "academical" purpose, this is a macro that automatically braces the next Unicode character.

It does requires patching `\big` however. Unavoidably.

How TeX input stream works is a bit complex, you still need TeX knowledge to *use* this macro i.e. it's not 100% automatic.

It only works in pdflatex -- nevertheless if you're using some Unicode engine you would not need this code at all.

Side note--if you use this in a package/extend the code etc., **fix the naming convention of `\__stored_content` etc. yourself**, see expl3 manual interface3.pdf.

(use `\tl_analysis_map_inline:nn` just to check if it's an active character instead of something like e.g. `\str_count:n`, to handle
some unlikely case that there's a length-1 control sequence and `\escapechar=-1`...)

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\errorcontextlines=100
\newunicodechar{‖}{\ensuremath{\|}}

\begin{document}


\ExplSyntaxOn

% command docs:
% if you execute `\__brace_next_unicode:nw {blob blob} ■` where ■ is any
% multi-byte UTF8 character, after some execution steps `blob blob {■}`
% will be executed. (spaces are only for demonstration.)

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__brace_next_unicode:nw #1 {
 \peek_N_type:TF {
  \tl_set:Nn \__stored_content {#1}  % actually this part can be done expandably
        % as well... but \peek_N_type:TF is already unexpandable
  \__brace_next_unicode_get_one_byte:N
 }
 {
  % do nothing, just put `blob blob` out
  #1
 }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__brace_next_unicode_get_one_byte:N #1 {
 \tl_analysis_map_inline:nn {#1} {
  \bool_set:Nn \__is_active_character { \token_if_eq_charcode_p:NN ##3 D }
 }
 \bool_if:nTF \__is_active_character {
  \int_compare:nNnTF {`#1} < {"80} {
   % not a part of multibyte UTF8 character, put it back.
   \__stored_content #1
  } {
   % part of multibyte UTF8 character.
   \int_compare:nNnTF {`#1} < {"E0} {
    % 2 bytes
    \__brace_next_unicode_handle_two:nn #1
   } {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {`#1} < {"F0} {
     % 3 bytes
     \__brace_next_unicode_handle_three:nnn #1
    } {
     % 4 bytes
     \__brace_next_unicode_handle_four:nnnn #1
    }
   }
  }
 }
 {
  % else, it could be a control sequence or similar. Do nothing with it.
  \__stored_content #1
 }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__brace_next_unicode_handle_two:nn #1 #2 {
 \__stored_content {#1 #2}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__brace_next_unicode_handle_three:nnn #1 #2 #3 {
 \__stored_content {#1 #2 #3}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__brace_next_unicode_handle_four:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 {
 \__stored_content {#1 #2 #3 #4}
}

%\__brace_next_unicode:nw {\pretty:nn {123}} ■

\NewCommandCopy \oldbig \big
\def \big {\__brace_next_unicode:nw {\oldbig}}

\ExplSyntaxOff




\[ ‖x‖ \]
\[ \big‖x\big‖ \]

% check that it still works in normal cases
\[ \big|x\big| \]
\[ \big|x\big| \]
\[ \big{|}x\big{|} \]
\[ \big{|}x\big{|} \]
\[ \big\lbrace x\big\rbrace \]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Consecutive `\[ ... \]` is actually not recommended.

Comment: Please, use the recommended naming scheme: `\__stored_content` does not fit. And also `\let\oldbig\big` is not good, and should be `\NewCommandCopy\oldbig\big` because `\big` is defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

Comment: `\[ \big \lbrace x\big\rbrace \]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That still work right? The peek_N_type returns a "false negative" i.e. returns false even if it's a N-type, but a `\lbrace` is not a partial UTF8 character and doesn't need bracing anyway. But yes, worth noting if someone else decide to modify the result and get strange result (generally-speaking \peek family of functions has a few special cases that they fails)

Comment: Actually the `\let` won't be "very harmful" as the fix is idempotent i.e. applying multiple times doesn't hurt

Comment: the edited version still fails as before: `! Improper alphabetic constant. <to be read again> 
                   \lbrace 
l.77 \[\big\lbrace
                   x\big\rbrace\]
? `