# amsmath and unicode-math compatibility

Tags: xetex, amsmath, unicode-math

I use a lot the unicode-math package to type directly unicode in the source, but there are some side effects that I do not fully understand.

Here is a MWE with just an equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\[\left\lVert \sum x_i-y \right\rVert\]
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Now here is what I get if I load the unicode-math package :

[image]

As you can see, the spacing is not the same, and the height of the \lVert and \rVert symbols is reduced.

So is it the expected behavior ? Is it a problem with loading order (it does not change anything if I load unicode-math first, though) ? Should I load some additional package ?

Note that the MWE does not use unicode, but in practice I do, so I would really like to understand how to get both working together, not a workaround to avoid using unicode-math.

Comment: Which engine are you using? xelatex or lualatex?

Comment: unicode-math changes the math font and the new font can have different font dimens and different glyph sizes. You don't need unicode-math "to type directly unicode" (what ever you exactly mean with this).

Comment: I am using xelatex, sorry I forgot to say that. Which other package can be used as a replacement ? (I mean, not necessarily controlling the math font, but being able to type unicode symbols in the source, that will be interpreted as the corresponding glyphs.)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex  (see all the answers, useful suggestions might be at the bottom. There are suggestions of `utf8x`, `unixode`, `unicode-math`