# What is the difference between inputenc and inputenx?

Tags: best-practices, input-encodings

Like I understood covers `inputenx` more cases as `inputenc`. Right, or is one of it obsolete? When not, what should I use in which case? I use `pdfTeX` version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (and `MiKTeX`).

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: Which engine do you use? If pdflatex, which version?

Comment: Hello @samcarter! Thank you for your comment! I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a current miktex (with a current LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 4) inputenc is already "built-in" and the default encoding is utf8. So I would ensure that all your files are utf8 encoded and use none of the packages.

If you find things that inputenx does better in your opinion I suggest to open an issue on the latex github site (https://github.com/latex3/latex2e) and to ask that the standard inputenc package is improved.

When I use one of the packages I prefer inputenc over inputenx as it evolves together with the latex format and so I expect less problems in the future with it.