# Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ² (U+B2)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \acro{I2C}[I²C]

Tags: errors, unicode, compilation-error, texdoc

Package inputenc Error: Unicode character `²` `(U+B2)(inputenc)` not set up for use with LaTeX. `\acro{I2C}[I²C]{Inter-Integrated Circuit}`

So I get this error I get when I try to compile my university latex template. Any suggestions please?

The code looks something like this:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper, 
12pt,
oneside,
BCOR1cm,
toc=chapterentrywithdots] 
{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}           % use for pdfLatex
\usepackage{makeidx} % f\"{u}r Benutzung des Befehls \printindex
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{acronym}

\hypersetup{%
bookmarksnumbered=true, hyperindex=true,
%
%Im Acrobat Reader Subtitel 1. Ebene anzeigen
bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,
%
pdfborder=0 0 0 % Keine Box um die Links!
}


\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{%
    \begingroup
    \tocsection
    \tocfile{\contentsname}{toc}
    \endgroup
}
\renewcommand*{\listoffigures}{%
    \begingroup
    \tocsection
    \tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
    \endgroup
}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{
    \begingroup
    \tocsection
    \tocfile{\listtablename}{lot}
    \endgroup
}
\begin{document}


\begin{titlepage}

{
    \begin{center}
        \raisebox{-1ex}{\includegraphics[scale=1.5] 
{Uni_positiv_gruen.pdf}}\\
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
}

\begin{center}

\LARGE{\textbf{Title of the thesis}}\\
\vspace{1cm}


\Large{\textbf{Thesis}}\\ 
\vspace{1cm}
Submitted in Fulfilment of the\\
Requirements for the Academic Degree\\
M.Sc.\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
Dept. of Computer Science\\
Chair of Computer Engineering
\end{center}
\vspace{3cm}
Submitted by: Max Mustermann\\
Student ID: 111222\\
Date: 12.12.1212\\
\vspace{0.3cm}\\
Supervising tutor: Prof. Dr. \\
(further supervisors)

\end{titlepage}

\addchap*{Abstract}
\blindtext
\\\\
\textbf{Keywords: Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, ...max 5}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\twocolumn
\addchap{List of Abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}[Bash]
\acro{KDE}{K Desktop Environment}
 \acro{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
 \acro{Bash}{Bourne-again shell}
 \acro{JDK}{Java Development Kit}
 \acro{VM}{Virtuelle Maschine}
 \acro{I2C}[I²C]{Inter-Integrated Circuit}
 \acro{KDE}{K Desktop Environment}
\acro{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
\acro{Bash}{Bourne-again shell}
\acro{JDK}{Java Development Kit}
\acro{VM}{Virtuelle Maschine}
\acro{I2C}[I²C]{Inter-Integrated Circuit}
 \acro{KDE}{K Desktop Environment}
\acro{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
\acro{Bash}{Bourne-again shell}
 \acro{JDK}{Java Development Kit}
 \acro{VM}{Virtuelle Maschine}
\acro{I2C}[I²C]{Inter-Integrated Circuit}
\acro{KDE}{K Desktop Environment}
\acro{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
\acro{Bash}{Bourne-again shell}
\acro{JDK}{Java Development Kit}
\acro{VM}{Virtuelle Maschine}
\acro{I2C}[I²C]{Inter-Integrated Circuit}
\acro{KDE}{K Desktop Environment}
\acro{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
\acro{Bash}{Bourne-again shell}
\acro{JDK}{Java Development Kit}
\acro{VM}{Virtuelle Maschine}
\acro{I2C}[I²C]{Inter-Integrated Circuit}
\acro{I2C}[I²C]{Inter-Integrated Circuit}
\end{acronym}

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{src/intro}  % Load Data from File intro.tex

\chapter{Tables}
\input{src/example_tables} % Load Data from File example_tables

\chapter{Figures}
\input{src/example_figures} % Load Data from File example_figures

\chapter{Referencing}
% Alternativ just write your text under \chapter like this example



\chapter{Subchapter}

\printindex 

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Generic question: [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex)

Answer (score 6):

As you don't provide the expected MWE, I don't know what `\acro` does.

But generally speaking, to declare unknown Unicode characters you should load:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and use:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{<unicode-in-hexa>}{<latex-code>}
```

that is to say in your case:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B2}{\ensuremath{{}^2}}
```

A simpler alternative :

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{²}{\ensuremath{{}^2}}
```

**EDIT (with the MWE)**

I have just pasted:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B2}{\ensuremath{{}^2}}
```

or

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{²}{\ensuremath{{}^2}}
```

at the beginning of the preamble of your MWE, and (after correction of `BCOR1cm` into `BCOR=1cm`) it works without any error or warning, and gives in both cases:

[image: output]

Comment: HI, I am trying to add the code, but it kind of comes as a block, I am not able to put it in code format. Help plz?

Comment: Hi, just updated the code. Now I know how to use the code structuring here. :)

Comment: I also get a lot more errors and multiple warning, if possible can any one elaborate on the others too?

Comment: @Newbee: I just compiled your code snippet and it return with no errors …

Comment: hi @current_user : how? Did u use any of the suggestion mentioned above?

Comment: @Newbee: Actually not – I just removed all the `input` files and complied it normally with `pdflatex` …

Comment: I edited my answer after a successful test of your code with my solution. 
Is it what you want ?
Which "lot more errors and multiple warning" areyou talking about ? Do they exists independantly of the "Unicode character ² (U+B2)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX" errot ?

Answer (score 2):

You’re running the legacy toolchain, which still uses 8-bit text encodings specific to LaTeX, and not loading the encoding that contains that character.

#### With Modern TeX Engines

The solution I recommend is to switch to LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and load `\usepackage{fontspec}` instead of `fontenc`.  This will switch you over to using Unicode and modern, standard fonts.  Places that still aren’t compatible with the newer toolchain should update.

#### With Type 1 Fonts

If you can’t do that, the LaTeX font encoding that contains `²` is [TS1, the text-companion encoding.](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf#subsection.A.2)  By default, LaTeX 3 will run `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` after your preamble and before `\begin{document}`.  It will convert UTF-8 characters into LaTeX commands, but because there are so many, and because some encodings overlap, it will only define the commands for encodings you have loaded.  For historical reasons back in the late twentieth century, you set up the TS1 encoding from the `textcomp` package.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

(If you’re interested, this is because, back when commercial Type 1 fonts were still around, they didn’t include most of the symbols from TS1 unless they were specifically designed for then-bleeding-edge TeX.  So, the package sets up the symbols your TS1 font actually contains.)

#### A Fallback

Another option is to load the `newunicodechar` package and define the command

```
\newunicodechar{²}{\textsuperscript{2}}
```

This is the only way to support certain other superscript characters in Unicode.