# What does mean the below error for my tex file?

Tags: pdftex, compilation-error

I posted a problem in [Scilag](https://www.scilag.net/problem/P-210709.1) , but I can't generate a pdf for it, First compilation give me the below error but i can't understand where is exactly my errors to fix them ?.

My compiled tex file:

```
Let ${\sigma}_x(n) =\sum_{d|n} d^x$ is the sum divisor function ,After a few computations in wolfram alpha about the divisor function for some values of $n$ to look the behavior of $\sigma_x(n)\bmod n$ for $\,n=6,\,$ We  got this result : $\sigma_x(6)=0 \bmod 6$ for $x$ odd and $2 \bmod 6$ if $x$ is even ,One can ask this question:Is $n=6$ the only integer satisfies $\sigma_x(n)
\equiv 0\bmod n$ for every odd integer  $x > 0$  and $2 \bmod n$ if $x$ is even integer ? One can  answer this question  using divisibility and Congruence properties  for sum power divisor function, you can see the proof  \href{https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.09941.pdf}{in this paper}  . The answer of this question yield to reformulate the following problem regarding periodicity on iterative of sum power divsior function .

\textbf{Problem}:Is $n=6$ the only integer satisfy periodicity on iterative of sum power divisor function  with small prime period namely $L=2$ ?

The challenging problem is that the analysis had some flaws.  However, one expects multiperfect numbers other than $1$ and $6$ to be a multiple of $4$; when $n$ satisfies $\sigma(n) \bmod n = 0$ and $\sigma_2(n) \bmod n = 2$, and in addition $ n \bmod 4  = 0$, then all odd prime factors of $n$ except one must occur to an even multiplicity, and the remaining odd prime factor must occur to a multiplicity of $1 \bmod 4$ and must be a prime that is $3 \bmod 4$.  While simple, these observations say a lot about $n$ and suggest that any numbers satisfying the title congruences are rare indeed, perhaps more so than odd multiperfect numbers, For more informations about the attempt which is given by Gerhard Paseman you may check this \href{https://mathoverflow.net/a/227569/51189}{MO answer}.

\textbf{Note}:The motivation behind solving the problem  is to add some properties for aliquot sequences and to find a new equivalence to the Riemann Hypothesis .
```

Logo error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.5.31)  9 JUL 2021 11:16
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**b3b0fcd2911181106c968a381397fd851625829229.tex
(./b3b0fcd2911181106c968a381397fd851625829229.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2017/10/31 v2.20.4
\linespacing=\dimen102
\normalparindent=\dimen103
\normaltopskip=\skip41
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip42

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen104
))
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen105
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count80
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 213.
\uproot@=\count81
\leftroot@=\count82
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 375.
\classnum@=\count83
\DOTSCASE@=\count84
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 596.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen106
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 712.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 713.
\macc@depth=\count85
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count86
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count87
\dspbrk@lvl=\count88
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count89
\column@=\count90
\maxfields@=\count91
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen107
\alignsep@=\dimen108
\tagshift@=\dimen109
\tagwidth@=\dimen110
\totwidth@=\dimen111
\lineht@=\dimen112
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip43
\multlinetaggap=\skip44
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2817.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 398.

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
\copyins=\insert199
\abstractbox=\box28
\listisep=\skip45
\c@part=\count92
\c@section=\count93
\c@subsection=\count94
\c@subsubsection=\count95
\c@paragraph=\count96
\c@subparagraph=\count97
\c@figure=\count98
\c@table=\count99
\abovecaptionskip=\skip46
\belowcaptionskip=\skip47
\captionindent=\dimen113
\thm@style=\toks19
\thm@bodyfont=\toks20
\thm@headfont=\toks21
\thm@notefont=\toks22
\thm@headpunct=\toks23
\thm@preskip=\skip48
\thm@postskip=\skip49
\thm@headsep=\skip50
\dth@everypar=\toks24
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
Package: color 2016/07/10 v1.1e Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 147.

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks25
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen114
\Gin@req@width=\dimen115
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty
Package: enumerate 2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
\@enLab=\toks26
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty
\wrapoverhang=\dimen116
\WF@size=\dimen117
\c@WF@wrappedlines=\count100
\WF@box=\box29
\WF@everypar=\toks27
Package: wrapfig 2003/01/31  v 3.6
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
Package: hobsub-generic 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen118
\Hy@linkcounter=\count101
\Hy@pagecounter=\count102

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count103

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `breaklinks' set `true' on input line 4383.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4509.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4514.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4517.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4524.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4529.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4762.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count104

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip11
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5115.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen119
\Fld@menulength=\count105
\Field@Width=\dimen120
\Fld@charsize=\dimen121
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6369.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6374.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6377.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6384.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6389.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6394.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6439.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6443.
\Hy@abspage=\count106
\c@Item=\count107
\c@Hfootnote=\count108
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count109
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count110

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip51
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/04/06 v1.3b Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks28
\inpenc@posthook=\toks29
)

Package hyperref Warning: Option `bookmarks' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 27.

Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 27.
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `pdftoolbar' set `true' on input line 27.
Package hyperref Info: Option `pdfmenubar' set `true' on input line 27.
Package hyperref Info: Option `pdffitwindow' set `false' on input line 27.
Package hyperref Info: Option `pdfnewwindow' set `true' on input line 27.
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 27.

(./b3b0fcd2911181106c968a381397fd851625829229.aux)
\openout1 = `b3b0fcd2911181106c968a381397fd851625829229.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 46.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 46.

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 46.

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count111
\scratchdimen=\dimen122
\scratchbox=\box30
\nofMPsegments=\count112
\nofMParguments=\count113
\everyMPshowfont=\toks30
\MPscratchCnt=\count114
\MPscratchDim=\dimen123
\MPnumerator=\count115
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count116
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks31
) (/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box31
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 46.

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count117
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 46.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 46.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 46.
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `b3b0fcd2911181106c968a381397fd851625829229.out'.


Overfull \hbox (3.0586pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 60--60
[]$[]$| 
 []


! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character φ (U+3C6)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.88 ...hird iterates of the φ- and σ-functions}
                                                  , Colloquium Mathematicum,...

? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.88 ...hird iterates of the φ- and σ-functions}
                                                  , Colloquium Mathematicum,...

You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter 

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 9818 strings out of 492647
 133136 string characters out of 6134766
 209826 words of memory out of 5000000
 13475 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 15077 words of font info for 58 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1302 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,13n,32p,847b,386s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Please could you add a full compilable code? I see a principal problem: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character. You have also an old version of TeXLive (2018). Are you using unicode characters?

Comment: @Sebastiano, I already added my tex file pleas check it

Comment: There are not the packages :-(. You should to put a code starting from \documentclass to  \end{document}. But have you done a copy and past on your site Scilag in a .tex file? :-(

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you have some literal φ and σ in your code which pdftex cannot interpret.

Comment: @campa, then what i can do to fix it ?

Comment: Either replace those symbols by appropriate `$\varphi$` and `$\sigma$ or look e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447237/82917

Comment: @campa, it is already fixed , the pdf is generated I didn't attract attention to my literator for phi and sigma i turned them using tex symbole

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is due to code not shown and was solved in comments.

Comment: @campa Hi, I not thought that Scilag use the internal your packages that they not must be declared. But there is an +1 on comment of the user below my answer and -1 for my answer: why? My MWE complile fine.

Comment: @Sebastiano Erm, sorry, I neither downvoted yours nor upvoted the other, but why are you asking me?

Comment: @campa Just to understand if I have done some mistakes considerating that in this discussion there was only you a part the OP.

Answer (score 2):

If I use this minimal working example of your (incomplete) code in `pdfLaTeX` works perfectly, without mistakes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Let ${\sigma}_x(n) =\sum_{d\div n} d^x$ is the sum divisor function. After a few computations in wolfram alpha about the divisor function for some values of $n$ to look the behavior of $\sigma_x(n)\bmod n$ for $n=6,$ we  got this result: $\sigma_x(6)=0 \bmod 6$ for $x$ odd and $2 \bmod 6$ if $x$ is even. One can ask this question: Is $n=6$ the only integer satisfies $\sigma_x(n) \equiv 0\bmod n$ for every odd integer $x > 0$  and $2 \bmod n$ if $x$ is even integer? One can  answer this question using divisibility and Congruence properties  for sum power divisor function, you can see the proof \href{https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.09941.pdf}{\url{in this paper}}. The answer of this question yield to reformulate the following problem regarding periodicity on iterative of sum power divsior function.

\textbf{Problem}:  $n=6$ the only integer satisfy periodicity on iterative of sum power divisor function  with small prime period namely $L=2$?

The challenging problem is that the analysis had some flaws. However, one expects multiperfect numbers other than $1$ and $6$ to be a multiple of $4$; when $n$ satisfies $\sigma(n) \bmod n = 0$ and $\sigma_2(n) \bmod n = 2$, and in addition $n \bmod 4  = 0$, then all odd prime factors of $n$ except one must occur to an even multiplicity, and the remaining odd prime factor must occur to a multiplicity of $1 \bmod 4$ and must be a prime that is $3 \bmod 4$. While simple, these observations say a lot about $n$ and suggest that any numbers satisfying the title congruences are rare indeed, perhaps more so than odd multiperfect numbers, For more informations about the attempt which is given by Gerhard Paseman you may check this \href{https://mathoverflow.net/a/227569/51189}{MO answer}.

\textbf{Note}: The motivation behind solving the problem is to add some properties for aliquot sequences and to find a new equivalence to the Riemann Hypothesis.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I already did this but it still doesn't work

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I have compiled (for example) with Papeeria: https://www.papeeria.com/p/0e6612c5-3f61-4c06-b12f-629ebc04ea86#/main.tex. I have had an image. Excuse me, but I not knew Scilag that load the packages. You can take only the part inside \begin{document} and \end{document} and you can try.

Comment: The code posted here does not generate the error as it does not involve the input shown in the error message. @zeraouliarafik should fix the example in the question so that it is _an example of the problem_.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I fully agree.

Answer (score 1):

A long comment , I think we do not need packages here since [Scilag](https://www.scilag.net/problem/P-210709.1) did  automatic compilation however there is no tex error upon compilation, The problem as @campa montioned out in comment that the problem occure in this reference "On the third iterates of the φ- and σ-functions" namely φ and σ , Just I fixed them using latex symbole as :$\phi$ and $\sigma$ yield to generated PDF successfully