# Unicode vs. WinEdt

Tags: pdftex, miktex, winedt

How do I represent and use some of the characters in the snippet below in Winedt 10.3 ?
I just want this for fun. I want a way how to create some of these characters
in a `pdflatex` compiler in WinEdt 10.3. Can someone give me a MWE of LaTeX file how to use them ? This a general question about how to use Unicode in WinEdt. Please note that I'm a complete beginner to LaTeX and Unicode especially. I need a MWE of the character 12110, **not** some lengthy answer.

[image]

Comment: Check this out: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34604/10898

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't use LuaTeX or XeTeX?

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, for some reasons I need LaTeX.

Comment: @user2925716 LuaTeX and XeTeX are just engines, they can compile LaTeX documents (by calling `lualatex <filename>` or `xelatex <filename>` just as you would with `pdflatex`, which's engine is called pdfTeX).

Comment: What's wrong with this MWE? : \documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{\dash}

\begin{document}


$\dash$

\end{document}

Comment: It is the wrong way around. `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` declares what to output if the Unicode character is read in the sources, not which macro to replace with a Unicode character. If you really want to use pdflatex you'd first have to find a font which has those symbols available and is usable under pdflatex. If you'd use `lualatex` instead, you'd just load a system font (provided by your OS) and input the Unicode character directly into the sources. As long as the used font has the glyph it'll work.

Comment: @user2925716 correct would be `\documentclass{article}\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{\dash}\newcommand*\dash{\textemdash}\begin{document}—\end{document}`.

Comment: For unicode, compiling with xelatex/lualatex and `fontspec` package is very easy: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface{\cuneiform}{Noto Sans Cuneiform}
\begin{document}
Cuneiform \cuneiform 
\end{document}`