# Using a Unicode Character in the Document

Tags: unicode

I would like to use star and crescent (U+262A) emoji in my document, even though I have read several articles in this environment, I couldnt realize how to do it. Please can anyone give me a hand?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible by using either `XELaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`...

Answer (score 2):

You need to employ a TeX engine that is Unicode-aware and can handle OpenType "smart" fonts. In short, use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, along with a font that has a non-empty entry for `\char"262A`.

E.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % for "\setmainfont" directive
\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol} % or some other suitable font
\begin{document}
\char"262A
\end{document}
```