# How to solve this package inputenc Error: Unicode character  (U+1D434)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: errors, input-encodings

How to solve this package issue. My code for annual report is too long. I cannot post here.

Comment: You don't need to post the whole code, we need a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that we can help you. Otherwise we have no idea which packages you're using, where this character occurs and so on.

Comment: Did you copy-and-paste text from some other document into your LaTeX document?

Comment: U+1d434 is   math italic A and normally in TeX that is just entered with a normal ascii A

Comment: Hello,
Thank you all for your kind reply. I closed the Texstudio and reopened and run the report again. Now the error is not coming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem has been solved, as noted in comments.

Comment: Generic question: [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex)

Answer (score 1):

One of your expressions uses  (U+1D434), the Unicode mathematical alphanumeric symbol italic *A*, instead of A.  This is probably because you copied from a PDF made with `unicode-math` or `mmap` or a webpage that uses MathML and pasted into your source file.

The simplest answer is to compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and load `\usepackage{unicode-math}`.

Otherwise, you can try to load `newunicodechar` and add the rule

```
\newunicodechar{}{\mathnormal{A}}
```

This might or might not work in all engines, due to being outside Unicode’s Basic Multilingual Plane.  (Thanks to David Carlisle for a good suggestion.)

Finally, you can search-and-replace every instance of  in your document with A.