# Typesetting unicode characters

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, logic

I try to use unicode characters in tex source:

```
\documentclass{article}
  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

∀
 
\end{document}
```

The universal quantifier does not typeset with xelatex.

pdflatex says

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ∀ (U+2200)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

What else should I use to typeset a universal quantifier given as a Unicode character?

Comment: You'll probably need to use a font that supports it.

Comment: LuaTeX seems to have a good support for a lot of fonts. I never play with it.

Comment: the help text for the pdftex error does tell you the command to use to define it (as in Ulrike's answer)

Comment: Special case of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to declare it, by default pdflatex supports only a subset.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2200}{\forall}

\begin{document}

$∀$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

For `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX`, many mathematical characters are defined in the `unicode-math` package

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF8
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$∀∃ℝ∈⟹$
\end{document}
```

[image]