# Typesetting mathematical unicode characters in typewriter font

Tags: math-mode, typewriter

This is a followup to this answer:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593973/27523

it suggests using the

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
```

command to use Unicode source characters.

Now the problem is that I use mathematical Unicode characters that need math mode so I used

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2200}{$\forall$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{22A2}{$\vdash$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2227}{$\land$}
```

which results in typesetting the characters but not with tt font as the surrounding alltt environment would dictate.

How can I make even the Unicode math symbols to appear in tt font?

Comment: I doubt that there are many typewriter fonts for pdflatex around which have the symbols, better use lualatex if you want to make typewriter math. And better don't switch to math mode inside the definition -- you won't be able to combine them in one math expression and  spacing will be wrong.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344214/use-latex-to-simulate-old-typewriter-written-texts/344272#344272  (you can use a unicode monospace font without the variation added in that answer)