# How to use unicode character in Overleaf

Tags: symbols, unicode

I want to use the symbol ⥁ (U+2941) in Overleaf, but when I try changing the compiler from pdflatex to XeLatex nothing happens. I also tried the advice given in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593950/typesetting-unicode-characters) but it does not work. What can I do?

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    $n⥁c$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem was due to the fact that I used folders and then wnated to use the symbol in one of the chapters. In general, a short TeX example code would be the following:

Comment: The problem, as in the link answer you linked, is that you need to use a font that contains that symbol. One way to do it is to follow Ulrike's answer. Another way is to load a font like Stix Two

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a suitable font eg with lualatex or xelatex

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}

\begin{document}

$ A ⥁ B \cwcirclearrow C $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good. But I see only a rectangle instead of the symbol.

Comment: @Sebastiano then you havent stix two installed or you have not set it up to be found with xelatex, try lualatex instead

Comment: David at this moment I am using the smartphone. Tomorrow start the school in SICILY 