# Bottom square bracket (U+23B5)

Tags: unicode, brackets, input-encodings

I'm looking for how to add a bottom square bracket (looks like this: ⎵) in latex (Overleaf specifically although I don't believe it should be different?).

According to [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex), this should work and is what I currently have:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{9141}{\bottomsquarebracket} % 9141 is 23B5 in decimal
...
\begin{document}
...
This is a bottom square bracket: \bottomsquarebracket
...
\end{document}
```

When compiled, I just get the text "This is a bottom square bracket: " as if the \bottomsquarebracket wasn't there at all.

I'm open to changing my code entirely if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you want it for, the visible space character from the cmtt fonts might be appropriate. You can access it with `\texttt{\verbvisiblespace}`¹

In the context of producing code that shows this symbol with spaces you can use `\verb*` or the `verbatim*` environment which work just like their non-`*` counterparts, but use the visible space character where spaces appear.

**Also**

You're using `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` wrong. The first argument should be *hex* so the correct value to enter there is `23B5` and not `9141`, *and* it's for mapping a Unicode input character to a LaTeX control sequence, not the inverse.

What you really want to do is use

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\bottomsquarebracket} \UnicodeEncodingName{"23B5}
```

---

1. `\verbvisiblespace` is one of those odd cases where commands work differently between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX. On the former, it will, not give the expected results without the `\texttt` but on the latter, the `\texttt` is redundant.

Comment: `\verbvisiblespace` should work with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in pdflatex, without the need for `\texttt`.

Comment: That's possible (I only looked at `source2e.pdf`). Vanilla LaTeX, though, defines `\DeclareRobustCommand\asciispace{\char 32 }` and for pdfLaTeX has `\let\verbvisiblespace\asciispace`

Comment: There's actually a fair amount of fiddling to make sure that whatever `\verbvisiblespace` is defined as, if it's not `\asciispace`, doesn't mess up spacing... part of the legacy of UTF8 being grafted onto a system that doesn't inherently support it.