# How to use U+1F54A (DOVE OF PEACE) with pdfLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, symbols, unicode

How can I use `U+1F54A DOVE OF PEACE` in my document,  especially with `pdfLaTeX` and not `LuaLaTeX`?

Comment: Special case of [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex/)

Comment: This would be much easier if you could actually use fonts that contain the required glyph.

Comment: Noto Sans Symbols2 have the glyph, but it is a  true type font  (not for pdflatex). However, using xelatex and the standalone class you can save it as PDF and then use some like \newcommand\dove{\includegraphics[width=1.5em]{dove.pdf}} in pdflatex

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it's not the exact same symbol, but [`fontawesome5`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5) has a dove icon.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\faDove
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [twemojis package](https://ctan.org/pkg/twemojis) with `\twemoji{1f54a}` or `\twemoji{dove}`. It works with PDFLaTeX.

Unfortunately the dove is hard to see against a white background, so here I made the background gray:

[image: twemoji dove of peace]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{twemojis}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{gray}
\twemoji{1f54a}
\end{document}
```

Other possibilities include embedding an image, or creating a tiny PDF cropped to just the emoji using lualatex with the [emoji package](https://ctan.org/pkg/emoji) (or any other software that supports emojis, cropped via [pdfcrop](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop?lang=en) or similar tool); that PDF could them be included in a pdflatex document via `\includegraphics`. (Not sure if that counts as "exclusively".)

Comment: thanks a lot! But is it possible to scale ```\twemoji{1f54a}```, i.e. to. make it slightly bigger or smaller ? In my document, for example, it is quite small, if compared to the text... :-)

Comment: Just for information to the readers of this thread, I had to install the package ```twemojis``` manually, because not included in my distribution... (1) I downloaded the package from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/twemojis?lang=en). (2) Through the Terminal of my laptop, I went inside the folder where the package was downloaded and I typed ```tex twemojis.ins```, in order to to get the file ```twemojis.sty``` (I do not know why ```tex twemojis.dtx``` did not work). (3) I copied and pasted ```twemojis.sty``` inside the folder where there is my ```.tex``` document and I compiled with ```pdfLaTeX```

Comment: You can use a scalebox, e.g., `\scalebox{4.5}{\twemoji{1f54a}}` to make it 4.5× its normal size. There's also `\texttwemoji{1f54a}` which will scale according to font size.

Comment: Actually I just found you can specify a height or width or scale directly as an optional parameter. `\twemoji[height=1in]{1f54a}`.

Comment: And to set the default height for all emojis: `\setlength{\twemojiDefaultHeight}{14pt}` or whatever. See the package documentation for more.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very very kind!! :-)

Comment: I am using both the emoji and twemoji packages, and the twemoji are noticeably smaller and slightly raised above the emoji. I was able to address the first option by passing a `[scale=0.5]` parameter to the twemoji (ironically that makes them a bit bigger), but I don't know what to do for their positioning. Also, I would rather use commands in the preamble to avoid having to do this every time, but the commands I found (such as the `\setlength` command suggested here) do not seem to have any effect on my document.