# Prevent line breaking around "-" in some phrases

Tags: line-breaking

How to prevent a line breaking at the character `-` in phrases such as `$k$-algebra`, without having to write like `$k$\nobreak-\nobreak algebra`?

Comment: Have you tried using a NON-BREAKING HYPHEN (U+02011) ?

Comment: @Ingmar Thank you for this suggestion, but how should I input this character?

Comment: Copy & paste (from here, e.g. ‑) or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex

Comment: @Ingmar Thank you, this works just as fine as Mico's answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `amsmath` package provides the `\nobreakdash` macro for just this case:

```
$k$\nobreakdash-algebra
```

The symbol that follows `\nobreakdash` need not necessarily be a `-` ("dash") character. It could aslo be something like

```
pages 1\nobreakdash--9
```

to indicate that no line break is allowed after "1\endash".