# Greek directly in math mode XeLaTeX instead of PdfLatex

Tags: math-mode, xetex, miktex, unicode, greek

This piece of code

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{alphabeta} 
\usepackage{amsmath}  


\begin{document}

$α+β+γ=\alpha+\beta+\gamma$

\end{document}
```

works perfectly in MiKTeX-TeXworks provided that I use the option pdfLatex.

However greek letters are ignored by when I use the XeLaTeX option.

I want to use XeLaTeX and yet be able to write  greek letters directly in math mode.

Is this possible?

If yes how should I modify the above piece of code?

Comment: Please extend your example to a full document (there is no documentclass)

Comment: use `unicode-math` not  `alphabeta` and you will be able to use all Unicode math characters

Comment: Somewhat special case of [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex/), for cross-linking purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

You can use `unicode-math` with xelatex and lualatex, it includes `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{unicode-math}  


\begin{document}

$α+β+γ=\alpha+\beta+\gamma$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not difficult to make `alphabeta` to do its job also for XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\iftutex
\newcommand\DeclareUnicodeCharacter[2]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~="#1\lowercase{\endgroup\protected\def~}{#2}%
  \catcode"#1=\active
}
\fi
\usepackage{alphabeta} 

\begin{document}

$α+β+γ=\alpha+\beta+\gamma$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: the package redefines `\alpha` to be `\TextOrMath{\textalpha}{\mathalpha}`, where `\mathalpha` is the original `\alpha`. The same for all other Greek letters.

After that it does

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B1}{\alpha}
```

in order to allow the user to type `α` to get an alpha in text or math mode. The code between `\iftutex` (which is true when using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and false otherwise) makes the Greek letter `α` active and provides a definition for them, which is exactly `\alpha` as redefine by `alphabeta` as mentioned above.

Of course, in order to use the Greek letters in text mode, you need a font that supports them.

[image]

If you plan to only use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can obviously omit `\iftutex` and `\fi`.