# lualatex convert --- to custom command automatically?

Tags: luatex

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34608/186406) shows a nicely spaced emdash. I'm wondering if with lualatex and all its power if it's possible to automatically convert `---` to the `\dash` command in the above link? (say with the toggles `\autodashON` and `\autodashOFF`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

You can replace `---` in the input by `\dash`

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand\dash{%
  \unskip\nobreak\thinspace\textemdash\allowbreak\thinspace\ignorespaces}

\directlua{
function dashes(s)
return string.gsub(s,'[-][-][-]','\string\\dash ')
end}

\def\autodashON{\directlua{%
luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer",dashes,"spaced em dash")%
}}
\def\autodashOFF{\directlua{%
luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer","spaced em dash")%
}}

\setlength\parskip{20pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}


One---two three --- four five.
One---two three --- four five.
One---two three --- four five.
One---two three --- four five.

\autodashON

One---two three --- four five.
One---two three --- four five.
One---two three --- four five.
One---two three --- four five.

\autodashOFF

One---two three --- four five.
One---two three --- four five.
One---two three --- four five.
One---two three --- four five.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very cool—thank you! Any thoughts towards using a technique like this to make TeX'ing a bit easier? Any immediate downsides come to mind?

Comment: @likethevegetable you need to be careful of verbatim, `---` possibly unlikely but `x--` common in C-like languages, also any --- coming from package code